# Web colors in an Android color XML resource file

Tags: android, xml

What do all of the X11/w3c color codes look like in the format of an Android XML resource file?

> I know this looks a tad ridiculous as a question, but given the votes apparently it's useful and since it clearly *does not* require an off-site resource I'm reformatting it to keep it around. --Editor.

Answer (score 1045, accepted):

You have surely made your own by now, but for the benefit of others, please find w3c and x11 below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
 <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="Ivory">#FFFFF0</color>
 <color name="LightYellow">#FFFFE0</color>
 <color name="Yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="Snow">#FFFAFA</color>
 <color name="FloralWhite">#FFFAF0</color>
 <color name="LemonChiffon">#FFFACD</color>
 <color name="Cornsilk">#FFF8DC</color>
 <color name="Seashell">#FFF5EE</color>
 <color name="LavenderBlush">#FFF0F5</color>
 <color name="PapayaWhip">#FFEFD5</color>
 <color name="BlanchedAlmond">#FFEBCD</color>
 <color name="MistyRose">#FFE4E1</color>
 <color name="Bisque">#FFE4C4</color>
 <color name="Moccasin">#FFE4B5</color>
 <color name="NavajoWhite">#FFDEAD</color>
 <color name="PeachPuff">#FFDAB9</color>
 <color name="Gold">#FFD700</color>
 <color name="Pink">#FFC0CB</color>
 <color name="LightPink">#FFB6C1</color>
 <color name="Orange">#FFA500</color>
 <color name="LightSalmon">#FFA07A</color>
 <color name="DarkOrange">#FF8C00</color>
 <color name="Coral">#FF7F50</color>
 <color name="HotPink">#FF69B4</color>
 <color name="Tomato">#FF6347</color>
 <color name="OrangeRed">#FF4500</color>
 <color name="DeepPink">#FF1493</color>
 <color name="Fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="Magenta">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="Red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="OldLace">#FDF5E6</color>
 <color name="LightGoldenrodYellow">#FAFAD2</color>
 <color name="Linen">#FAF0E6</color>
 <color name="AntiqueWhite">#FAEBD7</color>
 <color name="Salmon">#FA8072</color>
 <color name="GhostWhite">#F8F8FF</color>
 <color name="MintCream">#F5FFFA</color>
 <color name="WhiteSmoke">#F5F5F5</color>
 <color name="Beige">#F5F5DC</color>
 <color name="Wheat">#F5DEB3</color>
 <color name="SandyBrown">#F4A460</color>
 <color name="Azure">#F0FFFF</color>
 <color name="Honeydew">#F0FFF0</color>
 <color name="AliceBlue">#F0F8FF</color>
 <color name="Khaki">#F0E68C</color>
 <color name="LightCoral">#F08080</color>
 <color name="PaleGoldenrod">#EEE8AA</color>
 <color name="Violet">#EE82EE</color>
 <color name="DarkSalmon">#E9967A</color>
 <color name="Lavender">#E6E6FA</color>
 <color name="LightCyan">#E0FFFF</color>
 <color name="BurlyWood">#DEB887</color>
 <color name="Plum">#DDA0DD</color>
 <color name="Gainsboro">#DCDCDC</color>
 <color name="Crimson">#DC143C</color>
 <color name="PaleVioletRed">#DB7093</color>
 <color name="Goldenrod">#DAA520</color>
 <color name="Orchid">#DA70D6</color>
 <color name="Thistle">#D8BFD8</color>
 <color name="LightGrey">#D3D3D3</color>
 <color name="Tan">#D2B48C</color>
 <color name="Chocolate">#D2691E</color>
 <color name="Peru">#CD853F</color>
 <color name="IndianRed">#CD5C5C</color>
 <color name="MediumVioletRed">#C71585</color>
 <color name="Silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="DarkKhaki">#BDB76B</color>
 <color name="RosyBrown">#BC8F8F</color>
 <color name="MediumOrchid">#BA55D3</color>
 <color name="DarkGoldenrod">#B8860B</color>
 <color name="FireBrick">#B22222</color>
 <color name="PowderBlue">#B0E0E6</color>
 <color name="LightSteelBlue">#B0C4DE</color>
 <color name="PaleTurquoise">#AFEEEE</color>
 <color name="GreenYellow">#ADFF2F</color>
 <color name="LightBlue">#ADD8E6</color>
 <color name="DarkGray">#A9A9A9</color>
 <color name="Brown">#A52A2A</color>
 <color name="Sienna">#A0522D</color>
 <color name="YellowGreen">#9ACD32</color>
 <color name="DarkOrchid">#9932CC</color>
 <color name="PaleGreen">#98FB98</color>
 <color name="DarkViolet">#9400D3</color>
 <color name="MediumPurple">#9370DB</color>
 <color name="LightGreen">#90EE90</color>
 <color name="DarkSeaGreen">#8FBC8F</color>
 <color name="SaddleBrown">#8B4513</color>
 <color name="DarkMagenta">#8B008B</color>
 <color name="DarkRed">#8B0000</color>
 <color name="BlueViolet">#8A2BE2</color>
 <color name="LightSkyBlue">#87CEFA</color>
 <color name="SkyBlue">#87CEEB</color>
 <color name="Gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="Olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="Purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="Maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="Aquamarine">#7FFFD4</color>
 <color name="Chartreuse">#7FFF00</color>
 <color name="LawnGreen">#7CFC00</color>
 <color name="MediumSlateBlue">#7B68EE</color>
 <color name="LightSlateGray">#778899</color>
 <color name="SlateGray">#708090</color>
 <color name="OliveDrab">#6B8E23</color>
 <color name="SlateBlue">#6A5ACD</color>
 <color name="DimGray">#696969</color>
 <color name="MediumAquamarine">#66CDAA</color>
 <color name="CornflowerBlue">#6495ED</color>
 <color name="CadetBlue">#5F9EA0</color>
 <color name="DarkOliveGreen">#556B2F</color>
 <color name="Indigo">#4B0082</color>
 <color name="MediumTurquoise">#48D1CC</color>
 <color name="DarkSlateBlue">#483D8B</color>
 <color name="SteelBlue">#4682B4</color>
 <color name="RoyalBlue">#4169E1</color>
 <color name="Turquoise">#40E0D0</color>
 <color name="MediumSeaGreen">#3CB371</color>
 <color name="LimeGreen">#32CD32</color>
 <color name="DarkSlateGray">#2F4F4F</color>
 <color name="SeaGreen">#2E8B57</color>
 <color name="ForestGreen">#228B22</color>
 <color name="LightSeaGreen">#20B2AA</color>
 <color name="DodgerBlue">#1E90FF</color>
 <color name="MidnightBlue">#191970</color>
 <color name="Aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="Cyan">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="SpringGreen">#00FF7F</color>
 <color name="Lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="MediumSpringGreen">#00FA9A</color>
 <color name="DarkTurquoise">#00CED1</color>
 <color name="DeepSkyBlue">#00BFFF</color>
 <color name="DarkCyan">#008B8B</color>
 <color name="Teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="Green">#008000</color>
 <color name="DarkGreen">#006400</color>
 <color name="Blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="MediumBlue">#0000CD</color>
 <color name="DarkBlue">#00008B</color>
 <color name="Navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="Black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: I would dearly love to see some "good looking" buttons and other widgets using these colors. Like 8% of us I am color-blind and by buttons always look odd!

Comment: A more organized version for this [here](https://github.com/wtsang02/colors/blob/master/color.xml)

Comment: FYI for Monodroid developers: If you copy this snippet, make sure that all of your color names are lowercase.

Comment: [A better Version Arranged Alphabetically - 960colors](https://gist.github.com/VenomVendor/6857539),  [Arranged with ref to HEX - 960colors](https://gist.github.com/VenomVendor/6857547), A min version of are avail too

Comment: I'm really surprised that developers (every developer) has to add a standard colors.xml file to access colors in SVG or shape drawables. However, there are default colors available in layout XML files. Why aren't those colors (they appear to be defined per Android styles and not web standard colors) available to drawables? Or are they and I'm just missing it?

Answer (score 116):

You have to create the `colors.xml` file in the `res/values` folder of your project. The code of `colors.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="orange">#ff5500</color>
 <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
 <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
 <color name="date_color">#999999</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
 <color name="gray">#999999</color>
 <color name="blue">#0066cc</color>
 <color name="gold">#e6b121</color>
 <color name="blueback">#99FFFF</color>
 <color name="articlecolor">#3399FF</color> 
 <color name="article_title">#3399FF</color> 
 <color name="cachecolor">#8ad0e8</color>
</resources>
```

Or, you can use Colors in your application by following way

```
android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT;
```

Similarly

```
android.graphics.Color.RED;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of all that. It's just that the X11/W3c color set is such a standard, I was hoping someone might have one ready made!

Comment: Typo: in the `res/value` folder you need to place a file named `colors.xml`

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter what the name of the file is...  A common misconception of the Android framework is that the file names for various resources MUST have a specific name, which is not true.

Comment: The file name should be lower case though

Comment: @JohnAshmore corrent. However another big misconception is that the individual element names don't have to be.

Comment: @Justin Would you say though that it is a best/recommended practice to name resources as certain names? Like colour resources as `colour.xml`, etc?

Comment: @RestinPeace Yes, of course... but you can do things with the naming to help with organization of your files.  For example, you could have colors_dialog.xml if you had a specific set of colors for dialogs in your app. My point was just that the name of the file is arbitrary.

Comment: I see. Never thought about how naming could be used for organisation in such way. Thanks for taking time to provide your response.

Comment: it still doesn't seem to recognise my color, android studio complaints

Answer (score 32):

**I change all code to lower case for mono android**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="ivory">#FFFFF0</color>
    <color name="lightyellow">#FFFFE0</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
    <color name="snow">#FFFAFA</color>
    <color name="floralwhite">#FFFAF0</color>
    <color name="lemonchiffon">#FFFACD</color>
    <color name="cornsilk">#FFF8DC</color>
    <color name="seashell">#FFF5EE</color>
    <color name="lavenderblush">#FFF0F5</color>
    <color name="papayawhip">#FFEFD5</color>
    <color name="blanchedalmond">#FFEBCD</color>
    <color name="mistyrose">#FFE4E1</color>
    <color name="bisque">#FFE4C4</color>
    <color name="moccasin">#FFE4B5</color>
    <color name="navajowhite">#FFDEAD</color>
    <color name="peachpuff">#FFDAB9</color>
    <color name="gold">#FFD700</color>
    <color name="pink">#FFC0CB</color>
    <color name="lightpink">#FFB6C1</color>
    <color name="orange">#FFA500</color>
    <color name="lightsalmon">#FFA07A</color>
    <color name="darkorange">#FF8C00</color>
    <color name="coral">#FF7F50</color>
    <color name="hotpink">#FF69B4</color>
    <color name="tomato">#FF6347</color>
    <color name="orangered">#FF4500</color>
    <color name="deeppink">#FF1493</color>
    <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
    <color name="magenta">#FF00FF</color>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="oldlace">#FDF5E6</color>
    <color name="lightgoldenrodyellow">#FAFAD2</color>
    <color name="linen">#FAF0E6</color>
    <color name="antiquewhite">#FAEBD7</color>
    <color name="salmon">#FA8072</color>
    <color name="ghostwhite">#F8F8FF</color>
    <color name="mintcream">#F5FFFA</color>
    <color name="whitesmoke">#F5F5F5</color>
    <color name="beige">#F5F5DC</color>
    <color name="wheat">#F5DEB3</color>
    <color name="sandybrown">#F4A460</color>
    <color name="azure">#F0FFFF</color>
    <color name="honeydew">#F0FFF0</color>
    <color name="aliceblue">#F0F8FF</color>
    <color name="khaki">#F0E68C</color>
    <color name="lightcoral">#F08080</color>
    <color name="palegoldenrod">#EEE8AA</color>
    <color name="violet">#EE82EE</color>
    <color name="darksalmon">#E9967A</color>
    <color name="lavender">#E6E6FA</color>
    <color name="lightcyan">#E0FFFF</color>
    <color name="burlywood">#DEB887</color>
    <color name="plum">#DDA0DD</color>
    <color name="gainsboro">#DCDCDC</color>
    <color name="crimson">#DC143C</color>
    <color name="palevioletred">#DB7093</color>
    <color name="goldenrod">#DAA520</color>
    <color name="orchid">#DA70D6</color>
    <color name="thistle">#D8BFD8</color>
    <color name="lightgrey">#D3D3D3</color>
    <color name="tan">#D2B48C</color>
    <color name="chocolate">#D2691E</color>
    <color name="peru">#CD853F</color>
    <color name="indianred">#CD5C5C</color>
    <color name="mediumvioletred">#C71585</color>
    <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
    <color name="darkkhaki">#BDB76B</color>
    <color name="rosybrown">#BC8F8F</color>
    <color name="mediumorchid">#BA55D3</color>
    <color name="darkgoldenrod">#B8860B</color>
    <color name="firebrick">#B22222</color>
    <color name="powderblue">#B0E0E6</color>
    <color name="lightsteelblue">#B0C4DE</color>
    <color name="paleturquoise">#AFEEEE</color>
    <color name="greenyellow">#ADFF2F</color>
    <color name="lightblue">#ADD8E6</color>
    <color name="darkgray">#A9A9A9</color>
    <color name="brown">#A52A2A</color>
    <color name="sienna">#A0522D</color>
    <color name="yellowgreen">#9ACD32</color>
    <color name="darkorchid">#9932CC</color>
    <color name="palegreen">#98FB98</color>
    <color name="darkviolet">#9400D3</color>
    <color name="mediumpurple">#9370DB</color>
    <color name="lightgreen">#90EE90</color>
    <color name="darkseagreen">#8FBC8F</color>
    <color name="saddlebrown">#8B4513</color>
    <color name="darkmagenta">#8B008B</color>
    <color name="darkred">#8B0000</color>
    <color name="blueviolet">#8A2BE2</color>
    <color name="lightskyblue">#87CEFA</color>
    <color name="skyblue">#87CEEB</color>
    <color name="gray">#808080</color>
    <color name="olive">#808000</color>
    <color name="purple">#800080</color>
    <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
    <color name="aquamarine">#7FFFD4</color>
    <color name="chartreuse">#7FFF00</color>
    <color name="lawngreen">#7CFC00</color>
    <color name="mediumslateblue">#7B68EE</color>
    <color name="lightslategray">#778899</color>
    <color name="slategray">#708090</color>
    <color name="olivedrab">#6B8E23</color>
    <color name="slateblue">#6A5ACD</color>
    <color name="dimgray">#696969</color>
    <color name="mediumaquamarine">#66CDAA</color>
    <color name="cornflowerblue">#6495ED</color>
    <color name="cadetblue">#5F9EA0</color>
    <color name="darkolivegreen">#556B2F</color>
    <color name="indigo">#4B0082</color>
    <color name="mediumturquoise">#48D1CC</color>
    <color name="darkslateblue">#483D8B</color>
    <color name="steelblue">#4682B4</color>
    <color name="royalblue">#4169E1</color>
    <color name="turquoise">#40E0D0</color>
    <color name="mediumseagreen">#3CB371</color>
    <color name="limegreen">#32CD32</color>
    <color name="darkslategray">#2F4F4F</color>
    <color name="seagreen">#2E8B57</color>
    <color name="forestgreen">#228B22</color>
    <color name="lightseagreen">#20B2AA</color>
    <color name="dodgerblue">#1E90FF</color>
    <color name="midnightblue">#191970</color>
    <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
    <color name="cyan">#00FFFF</color>
    <color name="springgreen">#00FF7F</color>
    <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="mediumspringgreen">#00FA9A</color>
    <color name="darkturquoise">#00CED1</color>
    <color name="deepskyblue">#00BFFF</color>
    <color name="darkcyan">#008B8B</color>
    <color name="teal">#008080</color>
    <color name="green">#008000</color>
    <color name="darkgreen">#006400</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
    <color name="mediumblue">#0000CD</color>
    <color name="darkblue">#00008B</color>
    <color name="navy">#000080</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 31):

If you are just looking for the available colors that already exist with

```
@android:color/<color>
```

then you need to look in `android.jar >> android >> R.class >> R >> color`.

Here is the list that come with Android 4.4W I'm using:

```
background_dark
background_light
black
darker_gray
holo_blue_bright
holo_blue_dark
holo_blue_light
holo_green_dark
holo_green_light
holo_orange_dark
holo_orange_light
holo_purple
holo_red_dark
holo_red_light
primary_text_dark
primary_text_dark_nodisable
primary_text_light
primary_text_lignt_nodisable
secondary_text_dark
secondary_text_dark_nodisable
secondaryy_text_light
secondary_text_lignt_nodisable
tab_indicator_text
tertiary_text_dark
tertiary_text_light
transparent
white
widget_edittext_dark
```

Comment: This should be higher up on the list.  The default android color palette is quite substantial and significantly better than pasting default values into your colors.xml.

Answer (score 26):

I specifically was looking for the XML representation for Android.Graphics.Color.  I didn't find these, so here you are.  More details are in the [help document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="sysBlack">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="sysBlue">#FF0000FF</color>
    <color name="sysCyan">#FF00FFFF</color>
    <color name="sysDkGray">#FF444444</color>
    <color name="sysGray">#FF888888</color>
    <color name="sysGreen">#FF00FF00</color>
    <color name="sysLtGray">#FFCCCCCC</color>
    <color name="sysMagenta">#FFFF00FF</color>
    <color name="sysRed">#FFFF0000</color>
    <color name="sysTransparent">#00000000</color>
    <color name="sysWhite">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="sysYellow">#FFFFFF00</color>
</resources>
```

Of course, this is used like this:

```
android:textColor="@color/sysGray"
```

Answer (score 17):

With the help of excel I have converted the [link](http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm) above to android xml ready code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="Black">#000000</color>
    <color name="Gunmetal">#2C3539</color>
    <color name="Midnight">#2B1B17</color>
    <color name="Charcoal">#34282C</color>
    <color name="Dark_Slate_Grey">#25383C</color>
    <color name="Oil">#3B3131</color>
    <color name="Black_Cat">#413839</color>
    <color name="Black_Eel">#463E3F</color>
    <color name="Black_Cow">#4C4646</color>
    <color name="Gray_Wolf">#504A4B</color>
    <color name="Vampire_Gray">#565051</color>
    <color name="Gray_Dolphin">#5C5858</color>
    <color name="Carbon_Gray">#625D5D</color>
    <color name="Ash_Gray">#666362</color>
    <color name="Cloudy_Gray">#6D6968</color>
    <color name="Smokey_Gray">#726E6D</color>
    <color name="Gray">#736F6E</color>
    <color name="Granite">#837E7C</color>
    <color name="Battleship_Gray">#848482</color>
    <color name="Gray_Cloud">#B6B6B4</color>
    <color name="Gray_Goose">#D1D0CE</color>
    <color name="Platinum">#E5E4E2</color>
    <color name="Metallic_Silver">#BCC6CC</color>
    <color name="Blue_Gray">#98AFC7</color>
    <color name="Light_Slate_Gray">#6D7B8D</color>
    <color name="Slate_Gray">#657383</color>
    <color name="Jet_Gray">#616D7E</color>
    <color name="Mist_Blue">#646D7E</color>
    <color name="Marble_Blue">#566D7E</color>
    <color name="Slate_Blue">#737CA1</color>
    <color name="Steel_Blue">#4863A0</color>
    <color name="Blue_Jay">#2B547E</color>
    <color name="Dark_Slate_Blue">#2B3856</color>
    <color name="Midnight_Blue">#151B54</color>
    <color name="Navy_Blue">#000080</color>
    <color name="Blue_Whale">#342D7E</color>
    <color name="Lapis_Blue">#15317E</color>
    <color name="Cornflower_Blue">#151B8D</color>
    <color name="Earth_Blue">#0000A0</color>
    <color name="Cobalt_Blue">#0020C2</color>
    <color name="Blueberry_Blue">#0041C2</color>
    <color name="Sapphire_Blue">#2554C7</color>
    <color name="Blue_Eyes">#1569C7</color>
    <color name="Royal_Blue">#2B60DE</color>
    <color name="Blue_Orchid">#1F45FC</color>
    <color name="Blue_Lotus">#6960EC</color>
    <color name="Light_Slate_Blue">#736AFF</color>
    <color name="Silk_Blue">#488AC7</color>
    <color name="Blue_Ivy">#3090C7</color>
    <color name="Blue_Koi">#659EC7</color>
    <color name="Columbia_Blue">#87AFC7</color>
    <color name="Baby_Blue">#95B9C7</color>
    <color name="Light_Steel_Blue">#728FCE</color>
    <color name="Ocean_Blue">#2B65EC</color>
    <color name="Blue_Ribbon">#306EFF</color>
    <color name="Blue_Dress">#157DEC</color>
    <color name="Dodger_Blue">#1589FF</color>
    <color name="Butterfly_Blue">#38ACEC</color>
    <color name="Iceberg">#56A5EC</color>
    <color name="Crystal_Blue">#5CB3FF</color>
    <color name="Deep_Sky_Blue">#3BB9FF</color>
    <color name="Denim_Blue">#79BAEC</color>
    <color name="Light_Sky_Blue">#82CAFA</color>
    <color name="Sky_Blue">#82CAFF</color>
    <color name="Jeans_Blue">#A0CFEC</color>
    <color name="Blue_Angel">#B7CEEC</color>
    <color name="Pastel_Blue">#B4CFEC</color>
    <color name="Sea_Blue">#C2DFFF</color>
    <color name="Powder_Blue">#C6DEFF</color>
    <color name="Coral_Blue">#AFDCEC</color>
    <color name="Light_Blue">#ADDFFF</color>
    <color name="Robin_Egg_Blue">#BDEDFF</color>
    <color name="Pale_Blue_Lily">#CFECEC</color>
    <color name="Light_Cyan">#E0FFFF</color>
    <color name="Water">#EBF4FA</color>
    <color name="AliceBlue">#F0F8FF</color>
    <color name="Azure">#F0FFFF</color>
    <color name="Light_Slate">#CCFFFF</color>
    <color name="Light_Aquamarine">#93FFE8</color>
    <color name="Electric_Blue">#9AFEFF</color>
    <color name="Aquamarine">#7FFFD4</color>
    <color name="Cyan_or_Aqua">#00FFFF</color>
    <color name="Tron_Blue">#7DFDFE</color>
    <color name="Blue_Zircon">#57FEFF</color>
    <color name="Blue_Lagoon">#8EEBEC</color>
    <color name="Celeste">#50EBEC</color>
    <color name="Blue_Diamond">#4EE2EC</color>
    <color name="Tiffany_Blue">#81D8D0</color>
    <color name="Cyan_Opaque">#92C7C7</color>
    <color name="Blue_Hosta">#77BFC7</color>
    <color name="Northern_Lights_Blue">#78C7C7</color>
    <color name="Medium_Turquoise">#48CCCD</color>
    <color name="Turquoise">#43C6DB</color>
    <color name="Jellyfish">#46C7C7</color>
    <color name="Mascaw_Blue_Green">#43BFC7</color>
    <color name="Light_Sea_Green">#3EA99F</color>
    <color name="Dark_Turquoise">#3B9C9C</color>
    <color name="Sea_Turtle_Green">#438D80</color>
    <color name="Medium_Aquamarine">#348781</color>
    <color name="Greenish_Blue">#307D7E</color>
    <color name="Grayish_Turquoise">#5E7D7E</color>
    <color name="Beetle_Green">#4C787E</color>
    <color name="Teal">#008080</color>
    <color name="Sea_Green">#4E8975</color>
    <color name="Camouflage_Green">#78866B</color>
    <color name="Hazel_Green">#617C58</color>
    <color name="Venom_Green">#728C00</color>
    <color name="Fern_Green">#667C26</color>
    <color name="Dark_Forrest_Green">#254117</color>
    <color name="Medium_Sea_Green">#306754</color>
    <color name="Medium_Forest_Green">#347235</color>
    <color name="Seaweed_Green">#437C17</color>
    <color name="Pine_Green">#387C44</color>
    <color name="Jungle_Green">#347C2C</color>
    <color name="Shamrock_Green">#347C17</color>
    <color name="Medium_Spring_Green">#348017</color>
    <color name="Forest_Green">#4E9258</color>
    <color name="Green_Onion">#6AA121</color>
    <color name="Spring_Green">#4AA02C</color>
    <color name="Lime_Green">#41A317</color>
    <color name="Clover_Green">#3EA055</color>
    <color name="Green_Snake">#6CBB3C</color>
    <color name="Alien_Green">#6CC417</color>
    <color name="Green_Apple">#4CC417</color>
    <color name="Yellow_Green">#52D017</color>
    <color name="Kelly_Green">#4CC552</color>
    <color name="Zombie_Green">#54C571</color>
    <color name="Frog_Green">#99C68E</color>
    <color name="Green_Peas">#89C35C</color>
    <color name="Dollar_Bill_Green">#85BB65</color>
    <color name="Dark_Sea_Green">#8BB381</color>
    <color name="Iguana_Green">#9CB071</color>
    <color name="Avocado_Green">#B2C248</color>
    <color name="Pistachio_Green">#9DC209</color>
    <color name="Salad_Green">#A1C935</color>
    <color name="Hummingbird_Green">#7FE817</color>
    <color name="Nebula_Green">#59E817</color>
    <color name="Stoplight_Go_Green">#57E964</color>
    <color name="Algae_Green">#64E986</color>
    <color name="Jade_Green">#5EFB6E</color>
    <color name="Green">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="Emerald_Green">#5FFB17</color>
    <color name="Lawn_Green">#87F717</color>
    <color name="Chartreuse">#8AFB17</color>
    <color name="Dragon_Green">#6AFB92</color>
    <color name="Mint_green">#98FF98</color>
    <color name="Green_Thumb">#B5EAAA</color>
    <color name="Light_Jade">#C3FDB8</color>
    <color name="Tea_Green">#CCFB5D</color>
    <color name="Green_Yellow">#B1FB17</color>
    <color name="Slime_Green">#BCE954</color>
    <color name="Goldenrod">#EDDA74</color>
    <color name="Harvest_Gold">#EDE275</color>
    <color name="Sun_Yellow">#FFE87C</color>
    <color name="Yellow">#FFFF00</color>
    <color name="Corn_Yellow">#FFF380</color>
    <color name="Parchment">#FFFFC2</color>
    <color name="Cream">#FFFFCC</color>
    <color name="Lemon_Chiffon">#FFF8C6</color>
    <color name="Cornsilk">#FFF8DC</color>
    <color name="Beige">#F5F5DC</color>
    <color name="AntiqueWhite">#FAEBD7</color>
    <color name="BlanchedAlmond">#FFEBCD</color>
    <color name="Vanilla">#F3E5AB</color>
    <color name="Tan_Brown">#ECE5B6</color>
    <color name="Peach">#FFE5B4</color>
    <color name="Mustard">#FFDB58</color>
    <color name="Rubber_Ducky_Yellow">#FFD801</color>
    <color name="Bright_Gold">#FDD017</color>
    <color name="Golden_brown">#EAC117</color>
    <color name="Macaroni_and_Cheese">#F2BB66</color>
    <color name="Saffron">#FBB917</color>
    <color name="Beer">#FBB117</color>
    <color name="Cantaloupe">#FFA62F</color>
    <color name="Bee_Yellow">#E9AB17</color>
    <color name="Brown_Sugar">#E2A76F</color>
    <color name="BurlyWood">#DEB887</color>
    <color name="Deep_Peach">#FFCBA4</color>
    <color name="Ginger_Brown">#C9BE62</color>
    <color name="School_Bus_Yellow">#E8A317</color>
    <color name="Sandy_Brown">#EE9A4D</color>
    <color name="Fall_Leaf_Brown">#C8B560</color>
    <color name="Gold">#D4A017</color>
    <color name="Sand">#C2B280</color>
    <color name="Cookie_Brown">#C7A317</color>
    <color name="Caramel">#C68E17</color>
    <color name="Brass">#B5A642</color>
    <color name="Khaki">#ADA96E</color>
    <color name="Camel_brown">#C19A6B</color>
    <color name="Bronze">#CD7F32</color>
    <color name="Tiger_Orange">#C88141</color>
    <color name="Cinnamon">#C58917</color>
    <color name="Dark_Goldenrod">#AF7817</color>
    <color name="Copper">#B87333</color>
    <color name="Wood">#966F33</color>
    <color name="Oak_Brown">#806517</color>
    <color name="Moccasin">#827839</color>
    <color name="Army_Brown">#827B60</color>
    <color name="Sandstone">#786D5F</color>
    <color name="Mocha">#493D26</color>
    <color name="Taupe">#483C32</color>
    <color name="Coffee">#6F4E37</color>
    <color name="Brown_Bear">#835C3B</color>
    <color name="Red_Dirt">#7F5217</color>
    <color name="Sepia">#7F462C</color>
    <color name="Orange_Salmon">#C47451</color>
    <color name="Rust">#C36241</color>
    <color name="Red_Fox">#C35817</color>
    <color name="Chocolate">#C85A17</color>
    <color name="Sedona">#CC6600</color>
    <color name="Papaya_Orange">#E56717</color>
    <color name="Halloween_Orange">#E66C2C</color>
    <color name="Pumpkin_Orange">#F87217</color>
    <color name="Construction_Cone_Orange">#F87431</color>
    <color name="Sunrise_Orange">#E67451</color>
    <color name="Mango_Orange">#FF8040</color>
    <color name="Dark_Orange">#F88017</color>
    <color name="Coral">#FF7F50</color>
    <color name="Basket_Ball_Orange">#F88158</color>
    <color name="Light_Salmon">#F9966B</color>
    <color name="Tangerine">#E78A61</color>
    <color name="Dark_Salmon">#E18B6B</color>
    <color name="Light_Coral">#E77471</color>
    <color name="Bean_Red">#F75D59</color>
    <color name="Valentine_Red">#E55451</color>
    <color name="Shocking_Orange">#E55B3C</color>
    <color name="Red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="Scarlet">#FF2400</color>
    <color name="Ruby_Red">#F62217</color>
    <color name="Ferrari_Red">#F70D1A</color>
    <color name="Fire_Engine_Red">#F62817</color>
    <color name="Lava_Red">#E42217</color>
    <color name="Love_Red">#E41B17</color>
    <color name="Grapefruit">#DC381F</color>
    <color name="Chestnut_Red">#C34A2C</color>
    <color name="Cherry_Red">#C24641</color>
    <color name="Mahogany">#C04000</color>
    <color name="Chilli_Pepper">#C11B17</color>
    <color name="Cranberry">#9F000F</color>
    <color name="Red_Wine">#990012</color>
    <color name="Burgundy">#8C001A</color>
    <color name="Blood_Red">#7E3517</color>
    <color name="Sienna">#8A4117</color>
    <color name="Sangria">#7E3817</color>
    <color name="Firebrick">#800517</color>
    <color name="Maroon">#810541</color>
    <color name="Plum_Pie">#7D0541</color>
    <color name="Velvet_Maroon">#7E354D</color>
    <color name="Plum_Velvet">#7D0552</color>
    <color name="Rosy_Finch">#7F4E52</color>
    <color name="Puce">#7F5A58</color>
    <color name="Dull_Purple">#7F525D</color>
    <color name="Rosy_Brown">#B38481</color>
    <color name="Khaki_Rose">#C5908E</color>
    <color name="Pink_Bow">#C48189</color>
    <color name="Lipstick_Pink">#C48793</color>
    <color name="Rose">#E8ADAA</color>
    <color name="Desert_Sand">#EDC9AF</color>
    <color name="Pig_Pink">#FDD7E4</color>
    <color name="Cotton_Candy">#FCDFFF</color>
    <color name="Pink_Bubblegum">#FFDFDD</color>
    <color name="Misty_Rose">#FBBBB9</color>
    <color name="Pink">#FAAFBE</color>
    <color name="Light_Pink">#FAAFBA</color>
    <color name="Flamingo_Pink">#F9A7B0</color>
    <color name="Pink_Rose">#E7A1B0</color>
    <color name="Pink_Daisy">#E799A3</color>
    <color name="Cadillac_Pink">#E38AAE</color>
    <color name="Blush_Red">#E56E94</color>
    <color name="Hot_Pink">#F660AB</color>
    <color name="Watermelon_Pink">#FC6C85</color>
    <color name="Violet_Red">#F6358A</color>
    <color name="Deep_Pink">#F52887</color>
    <color name="Pink_Cupcake">#E45E9D</color>
    <color name="Pink_Lemonade">#E4287C</color>
    <color name="Neon_Pink">#F535AA</color>
    <color name="Magenta">#FF00FF</color>
    <color name="Dimorphotheca_Magenta">#E3319D</color>
    <color name="Bright_Neon_Pink">#F433FF</color>
    <color name="Pale_Violet_Red">#D16587</color>
    <color name="Tulip_Pink">#C25A7C</color>
    <color name="Medium_Violet_Red">#CA226B</color>
    <color name="Rogue_Pink">#C12869</color>
    <color name="Burnt_Pink">#C12267</color>
    <color name="Bashful_Pink">#C25283</color>
    <color name="Carnation_Pink">#C12283</color>
    <color name="Plum">#B93B8F</color>
    <color name="Viola_Purple">#7E587E</color>
    <color name="Purple_Iris">#571B7E</color>
    <color name="Plum_Purple">#583759</color>
    <color name="Indigo">#4B0082</color>
    <color name="Purple_Monster">#461B7E</color>
    <color name="Purple_Haze">#4E387E</color>
    <color name="Eggplant">#614051</color>
    <color name="Grape">#5E5A80</color>
    <color name="Purple_Jam">#6A287E</color>
    <color name="Dark_Orchid">#7D1B7E</color>
    <color name="Purple_Flower">#A74AC7</color>
    <color name="Medium_Orchid">#B048B5</color>
    <color name="Purple_Amethyst">#6C2DC7</color>
    <color name="Dark_Violet">#842DCE</color>
    <color name="Violet">#8D38C9</color>
    <color name="Purple_Sage_Bush">#7A5DC7</color>
    <color name="Lovely_Purple">#7F38EC</color>
    <color name="Purple">#8E35EF</color>
    <color name="Aztec_Purple">#893BFF</color>
    <color name="Medium_Purple">#8467D7</color>
    <color name="Jasmine_Purple">#A23BEC</color>
    <color name="Purple_Daffodil">#B041FF</color>
    <color name="Tyrian_Purple">#C45AEC</color>
    <color name="Crocus_Purple">#9172EC</color>
    <color name="Purple_Mimosa">#9E7BFF</color>
    <color name="Heliotrope_Purple">#D462FF</color>
    <color name="Crimson">#E238EC</color>
    <color name="Purple_Dragon">#C38EC7</color>
    <color name="Lilac">#C8A2C8</color>
    <color name="Blush_Pink">#E6A9EC</color>
    <color name="Mauve">#E0B0FF</color>
    <color name="Wisteria_Purple">#C6AEC7</color>
    <color name="Blossom_Pink">#F9B7FF</color>
    <color name="Thistle">#D2B9D3</color>
    <color name="Periwinkle">#E9CFEC</color>
    <color name="Lavender_Pinocchio">#EBDDE2</color>
    <color name="Lavender">#E3E4FA</color>
    <color name="Pearl">#FDEEF4</color>
    <color name="SeaShell">#FFF5EE</color>
    <color name="Milk_White">#FEFCFF</color>
    <color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Could you add mercury color?

Answer (score 13):

```
<!-- Black Transparent -->
<color name="transparent_black_hex_1">#11000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_2">#22000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_3">#33000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_4">#44000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_5">#55000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_6">#66000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_7">#77000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_8">#88000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_9">#99000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_10">#aa000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_11">#bb000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_12">#cc000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_13">#dd000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_14">#ee000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_hex_15">#ff000000</color>

<color name="transparent_black_percent_5">#0D000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_10">#1A000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_15">#26000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_20">#33000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_25">#40000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_30">#4D000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_35">#59000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_40">#66000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_45">#73000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_50">#80000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_55">#8C000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_60">#99000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_65">#A6000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_70">#B3000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_75">#BF000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_80">#CC000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_85">#D9000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_90">#E6000000</color>
<color name="transparent_black_percent_95">#F2000000</color>

<!-- White Transparent -->
<color name="transparent_white_hex_1">#11ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_2">#22ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_3">#33ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_4">#44ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_5">#55ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_6">#66ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_7">#77ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_8">#88ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_9">#99ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_10">#aaffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_11">#bbffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_12">#ccffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_13">#ddffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_14">#eeffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_hex_15">#ffffffff</color>

<color name="transparent_white_percent_5">#0Dffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_10">#1Affffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_15">#26ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_20">#33ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_25">#40ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_30">#4Dffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_35">#59ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_40">#66ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_45">#73ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_50">#80ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_55">#8Cffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_60">#99ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_65">#A6ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_70">#B3ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_75">#BFffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_80">#CCffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_85">#D9ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_90">#E6ffffff</color>
<color name="transparent_white_percent_95">#F2ffffff</color>
```

Comment: This answer is a bit overkill and underkill at the same time. It contains a lot of useless transparent colors but only for white and black.

Comment: Percentages are wrong. Since values are from #00 (0) to #FF (255), black at 50% opacity is #7f000000 because it has to be 127 as alpha channel, not 128. I've not checked other percentages but I assume they are subject to the same error. Don't get me wrong, it's impercettible to the human eye, but for the sake of correctness they should be fixed

Comment: @GiorgioAresu 127 is as close to 50% of 255 as 128 is.

Comment: @GiorgioAresu I don't quite understand why half of 0 ~ 255 is 127..Isn't it exactly 127.5? So if you round it, it became 128...It always has to be some difference between hex value and decimal value.

Comment: @TheFinestArtist yeah, my bad. I just didn't care to delete the answer, when I posted I was really tired, that's what too little sleep can do ;)

Comment: @GiorgioAresu It's fine, I was thinking whether I actually made it wrong. Really nice comments and too bad that we can't express exact colours using hex numbers..

Answer (score 10):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="Black">#FF000000</color>   
<color name="Black_overlay">#66000000</color>

<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_1">#11000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_10">#aa000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_11">#bb000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_12">#cc000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_13">#dd000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_14">#ee000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_15">#ff000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_2">#22000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_3">#33000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_4">#44000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_5">#55000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_6">#66000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_7">#77000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_8">#88000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_hex_9">#99000000</color>

<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_10">#1A000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_15">#26000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_20">#33000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_25">#40000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_30">#4D000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_35">#59000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_40">#66000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_45">#73000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_5">#0D000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_50">#80000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_55">#8C000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_60">#99000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_65">#A6000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_70">#B3000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_75">#BF000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_80">#CC000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_85">#D9000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_90">#E6000000</color>
<color name="Black_transparent_black_percent_95">#F2000000</color>

 <color name="BlanchedAlmond">#FFEBCD</color>
 <color name="Blue_AliceBlue">#F0F8FF</color>
 <color name="Blue_Aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="Blue_Aquamarine">#7FFFD4</color>
 <color name="Blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="Blue_BlueNavy">#000080</color>
 <color name="Blue_BlueViolet">#8A2BE2</color>
 <color name="Blue_CadetBlue">#5F9EA0</color>
 <color name="Blue_CornflowerBlue">#6495ED</color>
 <color name="Blue_DarkBlue">#00008B</color>
 <color name="Blue_DarkSlateBlue">#483D8B</color>
 <color name="Blue_DeepSkyBlue">#00BFFF</color>
 <color name="Blue_DodgerBlue">#1E90FF</color>
 <color name="Blue_Lavender">#E6E6FA</color>
 <color name="Blue_LavenderBlush">#FFF0F5</color>
 <color name="Blue_LightBlue">#ADD8E6</color>
 <color name="Blue_LightSkyBlue">#87CEFA</color>
 <color name="Blue_LightSteelBlue">#B0C4DE</color>
 <color name="Blue_MediumBlue">#0000CD</color>
 <color name="Blue_MediumSlateBlue">#7B68EE</color>
 <color name="Blue_MidnightBlue">#191970</color>
 <color name="Blue_Navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="Blue_PowderBlue">#B0E0E6</color>
 <color name="Blue_RoyalBlue">#4169E1</color>
 <color name="Blue_SkyBlue">#87CEEB</color>
 <color name="Blue_SlateBlue">#6A5ACD</color>
 <color name="Blue_SteelBlue">#4682B4</color>

 <color name="Brown">#A52A2A</color>
 <color name="Brown_BurlyWood">#DEB887</color>
 <color name="Brown_Chocolate">#D2691E</color>
 <color name="Brown_DarkKhaki">#BDB76B</color>
 <color name="Brown_RosyBrown">#BC8F8F</color>
 <color name="Brown_SandyBrown">#F4A460</color>

 <color name="Chartreuse">#7FFF00</color>
 <color name="Coral">#FF7F50</color>
 <color name="Cornsilk">#FFF8DC</color>
 <color name="Cyan">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="DarkMagenta">#8B008B</color>
 <color name="DarkOrchid">#9932CC</color>
 <color name="DarkSalmon">#E9967A</color>
 <color name="DarkTurquoise">#00CED1</color>
 <color name="DarkViolet">#9400D3</color>
 <color name="Fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="Gainsboro">#DCDCDC</color>

 <color name="Gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="Gray_DarkGray1">#A9A9A9</color>
 <color name="Gray_DarkGray">#2F4F4F</color>
 <color name="Gray_DimGray">#696969</color>
 <color name="Gray_LightGray">#D3D3D3</color>
 <color name="Gray_LightSlateGray">#778899</color>
 <color name="Gray_SlateGray">#708090</color>

 <color name="Green">#008000</color>
 <color name="Green_DarkGreen">#006400</color>
 <color name="Green_DarkOliveGreen">#556B2F</color>
 <color name="Green_DarkSeaGreen">#8FBC8F</color>
 <color name="Green_ForestGreen">#228B22</color>
 <color name="Green_GreenYellow">#ADFF2F</color>
 <color name="Green_LawnGreen">#7CFC00</color>
 <color name="Green_LightGreen">#90EE90</color>
 <color name="Green_LightSeaGreen">#20B2AA</color>
 <color name="Green_LimeGreen">#32CD32</color>
 <color name="Green_MediumSeaGreen">#3CB371</color>
 <color name="Green_MediumSpringGreen">#00FA9A</color>
 <color name="Green_PaleGreen">#98FB98</color>
 <color name="Green_SeaGreen">#2E8B57</color>
 <color name="Green_SpringGreen">#00FF7F</color>
 <color name="Green_YellowGreen">#9ACD32</color>

 <color name="Indigo">#4B0082</color>
 <color name="Khaki">#F0E68C</color>
 <color name="LemonChiffon">#FFFACD</color>
 <color name="LightCoral">#F08080</color>
 <color name="LightGoldenrodYellow">#FAFAD2</color>
 <color name="LightSalmon">#FFA07A</color>
 <color name="Lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="Linen">#FAF0E6</color>
 <color name="Magenta">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="Maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="MediumAquamarine">#66CDAA</color>
 <color name="MediumOrchid">#BA55D3</color>
 <color name="MediumPurple">#9370DB</color>
 <color name="MediumTurquoise">#48D1CC</color>
 <color name="MintCream">#F5FFFA</color>
 <color name="Moccasin">#FFE4B5</color>
 <color name="OldLace">#FDF5E6</color>
 <color name="Olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="OliveDrab">#6B8E23</color>

 <color name="Orange">#FFA500</color>
 <color name="Orange_DarkOrange">#FF8C00</color>
 <color name="Orchid">#DA70D6</color>
 <color name="PaleTurquoise">#AFEEEE</color>
 <color name="PapayaWhip">#FFEFD5</color>
 <color name="PeachPuff">#FFDAB9</color>
 <color name="Peru">#CD853F</color>

 <color name="Pink">#FFC0CB</color>
 <color name="Pink_DeepPink">#FF1493</color>
 <color name="Pink_HotPink">#FF69B4</color>
 <color name="Pink_LightPink">#FFB6C1</color>

 <color name="Plum">#DDA0DD</color>
 <color name="Purple">#800080</color>

 <color name="Red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="Red_Crimson">#DC143C</color>
 <color name="Red_DarkCyan">#008B8B</color>
 <color name="Red_DarkRed">#8B0000</color>
 <color name="Red_FireBrick">#B22222</color>
 <color name="Red_IndianRed">#CD5C5C</color>
 <color name="Red_LightCyan">#E0FFFF</color>
 <color name="Red_MediumVioletRed">#C71585</color>
 <color name="Red_MistyRose">#FFE4E1</color>
 <color name="Red_OrangeRed">#FF4500</color>
 <color name="Red_PaleVioletRed">#DB7093</color>
 <color name="Red_Tomato">#FF6347</color>

 <color name="SaddleBrown">#8B4513</color>
 <color name="Salmon">#FA8072</color>
 <color name="Seashell">#FFF5EE</color>
 <color name="Sienna">#A0522D</color>
 <color name="Silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="Tan">#D2B48C</color>
 <color name="Thistle">#D8BFD8</color>
 <color name="Turquoise">#40E0D0</color>
 <color name="Violet">#EE82EE</color>

 <color name="White_AntiqueWhite">#FAEBD7</color>
 <color name="White_Azure">#F0FFFF</color>
 <color name="White_Beige">#F5F5DC</color>
 <color name="White_Bisque">#FFE4C4</color>
 <color name="White_FloralWhite">#FFFAF0</color>
 <color name="White_GhostWhite">#F8F8FF</color>
 <color name="White_Honeydew">#F0FFF0</color>
 <color name="White_Ivory">#FFFFF0</color>
 <color name="White_NavajoWhite">#FFDEAD</color>
 <color name="White_Snow">#FFFAFA</color>
 <color name="White_Teal">#008080</color>

<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_1">#11ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_10">#aaffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_11">#bbffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_12">#ccffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_13">#ddffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_14">#eeffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_15">#ffffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_2">#22ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_3">#33ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_4">#44ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_5">#55ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_6">#66ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_7">#77ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_8">#88ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_hex_9">#99ffffff</color>

<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_10">#1Affffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_15">#26ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_20">#33ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_25">#40ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_30">#4Dffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_35">#59ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_40">#66ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_45">#73ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_5">#0Dffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_50">#80ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_55">#8Cffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_60">#99ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_65">#A6ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_70">#B3ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_75">#BFffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_80">#CCffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_85">#D9ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_90">#E6ffffff</color>
<color name="White_transparent_white_percent_95">#F2ffffff</color>

 <color name="White_Wheat">#F5DEB3</color>
 <color name="White_White">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="White_WhiteSmoke">#F5F5F5</color>

 <color name="Yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="Yellow_DarkGoldenrod">#B8860B</color>
 <color name="Yellow_Gold">#FFD700</color>
 <color name="Yellow_GoldenRod">#DAA520</color>
 <color name="Yellow_LightYellow">#FFFFE0</color>
 <color name="Yellow_PaleGoldenrod">#EEE8AA</color>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the improved answer from submitted by Lars: this works with the new android "L" (preview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <item name="White" type="color">#FFFFFFFF</item>
 <item name="Ivory" type="color">#FFFFFFF0</item>
 <item name="LightYellow" type="color">#FFFFFFE0</item>
 <item name="Yellow" type="color">#FFFFFF00</item>
 <item name="Snow" type="color">#FFFFFAFA</item>
 <item name="FloralWhite" type="color">#FFFFFAF0</item>
 <item name="LemonChiffon" type="color">#FFFFFACD</item>
 <item name="Cornsilk" type="color">#FFFFF8DC</item>
 <item name="Seashell" type="color">#FFFFF5EE</item>
 <item name="LavenderBlush" type="color">#FFFFF0F5</item>
 <item name="PapayaWhip" type="color">#FFFFEFD5</item>
 <item name="BlanchedAlmond" type="color">#FFFFEBCD</item>
 <item name="MistyRose" type="color">#FFFFE4E1</item>
 <item name="Bisque" type="color">#FFFFE4C4</item>
 <item name="Moccasin" type="color">#FFFFE4B5</item>
 <item name="NavajoWhite" type="color">#FFFFDEAD</item>
 <item name="PeachPuff" type="color">#FFFFDAB9</item>
 <item name="Gold" type="color">#FFFFD700</item>
 <item name="Pink" type="color">#FFFFC0CB</item>
 <item name="LightPink" type="color">#FFFFB6C1</item>
 <item name="Orange" type="color">#FFFFA500</item>
 <item name="LightSalmon" type="color">#FFFFA07A</item>
 <item name="DarkOrange" type="color">#FFFF8C00</item>
 <item name="Coral" type="color">#FFFF7F50</item>
 <item name="HotPink" type="color">#FFFF69B4</item>
 <item name="Tomato" type="color">#FFFF6347</item>
 <item name="OrangeRed" type="color">#FFFF4500</item>
 <item name="DeepPink" type="color">#FFFF1493</item>
 <item name="Fuchsia" type="color">#FFFF00FF</item>
 <item name="Magenta" type="color">#FFFF00FF</item>
 <item name="Red" type="color">#FFFF0000</item>
 <item name="OldLace" type="color">#FFFDF5E6</item>
 <item name="LightGoldenrodYellow" type="color">#FFFAFAD2</item>
 <item name="Linen" type="color">#FFFAF0E6</item>
 <item name="AntiqueWhite" type="color">#FFFAEBD7</item>
 <item name="Salmon" type="color">#FFFA8072</item>
 <item name="GhostWhite" type="color">#FFF8F8FF</item>
 <item name="MintCream" type="color">#FFF5FFFA</item>
 <item name="WhiteSmoke" type="color">#FFF5F5F5</item>
 <item name="Beige" type="color">#FFF5F5DC</item>
 <item name="Wheat" type="color">#FFF5DEB3</item>
 <item name="SandyBrown" type="color">#FFF4A460</item>
 <item name="Azure" type="color">#FFF0FFFF</item>
 <item name="Honeydew" type="color">#FFF0FFF0</item>
 <item name="AliceBlue" type="color">#FFF0F8FF</item>
 <item name="Khaki" type="color">#FFF0E68C</item>
 <item name="LightCoral" type="color">#FFF08080</item>
 <item name="PaleGoldenrod" type="color">#FFEEE8AA</item>
 <item name="Violet" type="color">#FFEE82EE</item>
 <item name="DarkSalmon" type="color">#FFE9967A</item>
 <item name="Lavender" type="color">#FFE6E6FA</item>
 <item name="LightCyan" type="color">#FFE0FFFF</item>
 <item name="BurlyWood" type="color">#FFDEB887</item>
 <item name="Plum" type="color">#FFDDA0DD</item>
 <item name="Gainsboro" type="color">#FFDCDCDC</item>
 <item name="Crimson" type="color">#FFDC143C</item>
 <item name="PaleVioletRed" type="color">#FFDB7093</item>
 <item name="Goldenrod" type="color">#FFDAA520</item>
 <item name="Orchid" type="color">#FFDA70D6</item>
 <item name="Thistle" type="color">#FFD8BFD8</item>
 <item name="LightGrey" type="color">#FFD3D3D3</item>
 <item name="Tan" type="color">#FFD2B48C</item>
 <item name="Chocolate" type="color">#FFD2691E</item>
 <item name="Peru" type="color">#FFCD853F</item>
 <item name="IndianRed" type="color">#FFCD5C5C</item>
 <item name="MediumVioletRed" type="color">#FFC71585</item>
 <item name="Silver" type="color">#FFC0C0C0</item>
 <item name="DarkKhaki" type="color">#FFBDB76B</item>
 <item name="RosyBrown" type="color">#FFBC8F8F</item>
 <item name="MediumOrchid" type="color">#FFBA55D3</item>
 <item name="DarkGoldenrod" type="color">#FFB8860B</item>
 <item name="FireBrick" type="color">#FFB22222</item>
 <item name="PowderBlue" type="color">#FFB0E0E6</item>
 <item name="LightSteelBlue" type="color">#FFB0C4DE</item>
 <item name="PaleTurquoise" type="color">#FFAFEEEE</item>
 <item name="GreenYellow" type="color">#FFADFF2F</item>
 <item name="LightBlue" type="color">#FFADD8E6</item>
 <item name="DarkGray" type="color">#FFA9A9A9</item>
 <item name="Brown" type="color">#FFA52A2A</item>
 <item name="Sienna" type="color">#FFA0522D</item>
 <item name="YellowGreen" type="color">#FF9ACD32</item>
 <item name="DarkOrchid" type="color">#FF9932CC</item>
 <item name="PaleGreen" type="color">#FF98FB98</item>
 <item name="DarkViolet" type="color">#FF9400D3</item>
 <item name="MediumPurple" type="color">#FF9370DB</item>
 <item name="LightGreen" type="color">#FF90EE90</item>
 <item name="DarkSeaGreen" type="color">#FF8FBC8F</item>
 <item name="SaddleBrown" type="color">#FF8B4513</item>
 <item name="DarkMagenta" type="color">#FF8B008B</item>
 <item name="DarkRed" type="color">#FF8B0000</item>
 <item name="BlueViolet" type="color">#FF8A2BE2</item>
 <item name="LightSkyBlue" type="color">#FF87CEFA</item>
 <item name="SkyBlue" type="color">#FF87CEEB</item>
 <item name="Gray" type="color">#FF808080</item>
 <item name="Olive" type="color">#FF808000</item>
 <item name="Purple" type="color">#FF800080</item>
 <item name="Maroon" type="color">#FF800000</item>
 <item name="Aquamarine" type="color">#FF7FFFD4</item>
 <item name="Chartreuse" type="color">#FF7FFF00</item>
 <item name="LawnGreen" type="color">#FF7CFC00</item>
 <item name="MediumSlateBlue" type="color">#FF7B68EE</item>
 <item name="LightSlateGray" type="color">#FF778899</item>
 <item name="SlateGray" type="color">#FF708090</item>
 <item name="OliveDrab" type="color">#FF6B8E23</item>
 <item name="SlateBlue" type="color">#FF6A5ACD</item>
 <item name="DimGray" type="color">#FF696969</item>
 <item name="MediumAquamarine" type="color">#FF66CDAA</item>
 <item name="CornflowerBlue" type="color">#FF6495ED</item>
 <item name="CadetBlue" type="color">#FF5F9EA0</item>
 <item name="DarkOliveGreen" type="color">#FF556B2F</item>
 <item name="Indigo" type="color">#FF4B0082</item>
 <item name="MediumTurquoise" type="color">#FF48D1CC</item>
 <item name="DarkSlateBlue" type="color">#FF483D8B</item>
 <item name="SteelBlue" type="color">#FF4682B4</item>
 <item name="RoyalBlue" type="color">#FF4169E1</item>
 <item name="Turquoise" type="color">#FF40E0D0</item>
 <item name="MediumSeaGreen" type="color">#FF3CB371</item>
 <item name="LimeGreen" type="color">#FF32CD32</item>
 <item name="DarkSlateGray" type="color">#FF2F4F4F</item>
 <item name="SeaGreen" type="color">#FF2E8B57</item>
 <item name="ForestGreen" type="color">#FF228B22</item>
 <item name="LightSeaGreen" type="color">#FF20B2AA</item>
 <item name="DodgerBlue" type="color">#FF1E90FF</item>
 <item name="MidnightBlue" type="color">#FF191970</item>
 <item name="Aqua" type="color">#FF00FFFF</item>
 <item name="Cyan" type="color">#FF00FFFF</item>
 <item name="SpringGreen" type="color">#FF00FF7F</item>
 <item name="Lime" type="color">#FF00FF00</item>
 <item name="MediumSpringGreen" type="color">#FF00FA9A</item>
 <item name="DarkTurquoise" type="color">#FF00CED1</item>
 <item name="DeepSkyBlue" type="color">#FF00BFFF</item>
 <item name="DarkCyan" type="color">#FF008B8B</item>
 <item name="Teal" type="color">#FF008080</item>
 <item name="Green" type="color">#FF008000</item>
 <item name="DarkGreen" type="color">#FF006400</item>
 <item name="Blue" type="color">#FF0000FF</item>
 <item name="MediumBlue" type="color">#FF0000CD</item>
 <item name="DarkBlue" type="color">#FF00008B</item>
 <item name="Navy" type="color">#FF000080</item>
 <item name="Black" type="color">#FF000000</item>

 <integer-array name="androidcolors">

         <item>@color/White</item>
         <item>@color/Ivory</item>
         <item>@color/LightYellow</item>
         <item>@color/Yellow</item>
         <item>@color/Snow</item>
         <item>@color/FloralWhite</item>
         <item>@color/LemonChiffon</item>
         <item>@color/Cornsilk</item>
         <item>@color/Seashell</item>
         <item>@color/LavenderBlush</item>
         <item>@color/PapayaWhip</item>
         <item>@color/BlanchedAlmond</item>
         <item>@color/MistyRose</item>
         <item>@color/Bisque</item>
         <item>@color/Moccasin</item>
         <item>@color/NavajoWhite</item>
         <item>@color/PeachPuff</item>
         <item>@color/Gold</item>
         <item>@color/Pink</item>
         <item>@color/LightPink</item>
         <item>@color/Orange</item>
         <item>@color/LightSalmon</item>
         <item>@color/DarkOrange</item>
         <item>@color/Coral</item>
         <item>@color/HotPink</item>
         <item>@color/Tomato</item>
         <item>@color/OrangeRed</item>
         <item>@color/DeepPink</item>
         <item>@color/Fuchsia</item>
         <item>@color/Magenta</item>
         <item>@color/Red</item>
         <item>@color/OldLace</item>
         <item>@color/LightGoldenrodYellow</item>
         <item>@color/Linen</item>
         <item>@color/AntiqueWhite</item>
         <item>@color/Salmon</item>
         <item>@color/GhostWhite</item>
         <item>@color/MintCream</item>
         <item>@color/WhiteSmoke</item>
         <item>@color/Beige</item>
         <item>@color/Wheat</item>
         <item>@color/SandyBrown</item>
         <item>@color/Azure</item>
         <item>@color/Honeydew</item>
         <item>@color/AliceBlue</item>
         <item>@color/Khaki</item>
         <item>@color/LightCoral</item>
         <item>@color/PaleGoldenrod</item>
         <item>@color/Violet</item>
         <item>@color/DarkSalmon</item>
         <item>@color/Lavender</item>
         <item>@color/LightCyan</item>
         <item>@color/BurlyWood</item>
         <item>@color/Plum</item>
         <item>@color/Gainsboro</item>
         <item>@color/Crimson</item>
         <item>@color/PaleVioletRed</item>
         <item>@color/Goldenrod</item>
         <item>@color/Orchid</item>
         <item>@color/Thistle</item>
         <item>@color/LightGrey</item>
         <item>@color/Tan</item>
         <item>@color/Chocolate</item>
         <item>@color/Peru</item>
         <item>@color/IndianRed</item>
         <item>@color/MediumVioletRed</item>
         <item>@color/Silver</item>
         <item>@color/DarkKhaki</item>
         <item>@color/RosyBrown</item>
         <item>@color/MediumOrchid</item>
         <item>@color/DarkGoldenrod</item>
         <item>@color/FireBrick</item>
         <item>@color/PowderBlue</item>
         <item>@color/LightSteelBlue</item>
         <item>@color/PaleTurquoise</item>
         <item>@color/GreenYellow</item>
         <item>@color/LightBlue</item>
         <item>@color/DarkGray</item>
         <item>@color/Brown</item>
         <item>@color/Sienna</item>
         <item>@color/YellowGreen</item>
         <item>@color/DarkOrchid</item>
         <item>@color/PaleGreen</item>
         <item>@color/DarkViolet</item>
         <item>@color/MediumPurple</item>
         <item>@color/LightGreen</item>
         <item>@color/DarkSeaGreen</item>
         <item>@color/SaddleBrown</item>
         <item>@color/DarkMagenta</item>
         <item>@color/DarkRed</item>
         <item>@color/BlueViolet</item>
         <item>@color/LightSkyBlue</item>
         <item>@color/SkyBlue</item>
         <item>@color/Gray</item>
         <item>@color/Olive</item>
         <item>@color/Purple</item>
         <item>@color/Maroon</item>
         <item>@color/Aquamarine</item>
         <item>@color/Chartreuse</item>
         <item>@color/LawnGreen</item>
         <item>@color/MediumSlateBlue</item>
         <item>@color/LightSlateGray</item>
         <item>@color/SlateGray</item>
         <item>@color/OliveDrab</item>
         <item>@color/SlateBlue</item>
         <item>@color/DimGray</item>
         <item>@color/MediumAquamarine</item>
         <item>@color/CornflowerBlue</item>
         <item>@color/CadetBlue</item>
         <item>@color/DarkOliveGreen</item>
         <item>@color/Indigo</item>
         <item>@color/MediumTurquoise</item>
         <item>@color/DarkSlateBlue</item>
         <item>@color/SteelBlue</item>
         <item>@color/RoyalBlue</item>
         <item>@color/Turquoise</item>
         <item>@color/MediumSeaGreen</item>
         <item>@color/LimeGreen</item>
         <item>@color/DarkSlateGray</item>
         <item>@color/SeaGreen</item>
         <item>@color/ForestGreen</item>
         <item>@color/LightSeaGreen</item>
         <item>@color/DodgerBlue</item>
         <item>@color/MidnightBlue</item>
         <item>@color/Aqua</item>
         <item>@color/Cyan</item>
         <item>@color/SpringGreen</item>
         <item>@color/Lime</item>
         <item>@color/MediumSpringGreen</item>
         <item>@color/DarkTurquoise</item>
         <item>@color/DeepSkyBlue</item>
         <item>@color/DarkCyan</item>
         <item>@color/Teal</item>
         <item>@color/Green</item>
         <item>@color/DarkGreen</item>
         <item>@color/Blue</item>
         <item>@color/MediumBlue</item>
         <item>@color/DarkBlue</item>
         <item>@color/Navy</item>
         <item>@color/Black</item>

     </integer-array>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit Answer of @rolnad :-Remove White space from name

```
<color name="Black">#000000</color>
<color name="Gunmetal">#2C3539</color>
<color name="Midnight">#2B1B17</color>
<color name="Charcoal">#34282C</color>
<color name="DarkSlateGrey">#25383C</color>
<color name="Oil">#3B3131</color>
<color name="BlackCat">#413839</color>
<color name="BlackEel">#463E3F</color>
<color name="BlackCow">#4C4646</color>
<color name="GrayWolf">#504A4B</color>
<color name="VampireGray">#565051</color>
<color name="GrayDolphin">#5C5858</color>
<color name="CarbonGray">#625D5D</color>
<color name="AshGray">#666362</color>
<color name="CloudyGray">#6D6968</color>
<color name="SmokeyGray">#726E6D</color>
<color name="Gray">#736F6E</color>
<color name="Granite">#837E7C</color>
<color name="BattleshipGray">#848482</color>
<color name="GrayCloud">#B6B6B4</color>
<color name="GrayGoose">#D1D0CE</color>
<color name="Platinum">#E5E4E2</color>
<color name="MetallicSilver">#BCC6CC</color>
<color name="BlueGray">#98AFC7</color>
<color name="LightSlateGray">#6D7B8D</color>
<color name="SlateGray">#657383</color>
<color name="JetGray">#616D7E</color>
<color name="MistBlue">#646D7E</color>
<color name="MarbleBlue">#566D7E</color>
<color name="SteelBlue">#4863A0</color>
<color name="BlueJay">#2B547E</color>
<color name="DarkSlateBlue">#2B3856</color>
<color name="MidnightBlue">#151B54</color>
<color name="NavyBlue">#000080</color>
<color name="BlueWhale">#342D7E</color>
<color name="LapisBlue">#15317E</color>
<color name="EarthBlue">#0000A0</color>
<color name="CobaltBlue">#0020C2</color>
<color name="BlueberryBlue">#0041C2</color>
<color name="SapphireBlue">#2554C7</color>
<color name="BlueEyes">#1569C7</color>
<color name="RoyalBlue">#2B60DE</color>
<color name="BlueOrchid">#1F45FC</color>
<color name="BlueLotus">#6960EC</color>
<color name="LightSlateBlue">#736AFF</color>
<color name="Slate_Blue">#357EC7</color>
<color name="SilkBlue">#488AC7</color>
<color name="BlueIvy">#3090C7</color>
<color name="BlueKoi">#659EC7</color>
<color name="ColumbiaBlue">#87AFC7</color>
<color name="BabyBlue">#95B9C7</color>
<color name="LightSteelBlue">#728FCE</color>
<color name="OceanBlue">#2B65EC</color>
<color name="BlueRibbon">#306EFF</color>
<color name="BlueDress">#157DEC</color>
<color name="DodgerBlue">#1589FF</color>
<color name="Cornflower_Blue">#6495ED</color>
<color name="ButterflyBlue">#38ACEC</color>
<color name="Iceberg">#56A5EC</color>
<color name="CrystalBlue">#5CB3FF</color>
<color name="DeepSkyBlue">#3BB9FF</color>
<color name="DenimBlue">#79BAEC</color>
<color name="LightSkyBlue">#82CAFA</color>
<color name="SkyBlue">#82CAFF</color>
<color name="JeansBlue">#A0CFEC</color>
<color name="BlueAngel">#B7CEEC</color>
<color name="PastelBlue">#B4CFEC</color>
<color name="SeaBlue">#C2DFFF</color>
<color name="PowderBlue">#C6DEFF</color>
<color name="CoralBlue">#AFDCEC</color>
<color name="LightBlue">#ADDFFF</color>
<color name="RobinEggBlue">#BDEDFF</color>
<color name="PaleBlueLily">#CFECEC</color>
<color name="LightCyan">#E0FFFF</color>
<color name="Water">#EBF4FA</color>
<color name="AliceBlue">#F0F8FF</color>
<color name="Azure">#F0FFFF</color>
<color name="LightSlate">#CCFFFF</color>
<color name="LightAquamarine">#93FFE8</color>
<color name="ElectricBlue">#9AFEFF</color>
<color name="Aquamarine">#7FFFD4</color>
<color name="CyanorAqua">#00FFFF</color>
<color name="TronBlue">#7DFDFE</color>
<color name="BlueZircon">#57FEFF</color>
<color name="BlueLagoon">#8EEBEC</color>
<color name="Celeste">#50EBEC</color>
<color name="BlueDiamond">#4EE2EC</color>
<color name="TiffanyBlue">#81D8D0</color>
<color name="CyanOpaque">#92C7C7</color>
<color name="BlueHosta">#77BFC7</color>
<color name="NorthernLightsBlue">#78C7C7</color>
<color name="MediumTurquoise">#48CCCD</color>
<color name="Turquoise">#43C6DB</color>
<color name="Jellyfish">#46C7C7</color>
<color name="MascawBlueGreen">#43BFC7</color>
<color name="LightSeaGreen">#3EA99F</color>
<color name="DarkTurquoise">#3B9C9C</color>
<color name="SeaTurtleGreen">#438D80</color>
<color name="MediumAquamarine">#348781</color>
<color name="GreenishBlue">#307D7E</color>
<color name="GrayishTurquoise">#5E7D7E</color>
<color name="BeetleGreen">#4C787E</color>
<color name="Teal">#008080</color>
<color name="SeaGreen">#4E8975</color>
<color name="CamouflageGreen">#78866B</color>
<color name="HazelGreen">#617C58</color>
<color name="VenomGreen">#728C00</color>
<color name="FernGreen">#667C26</color>
<color name="DarkForrestGreen">#254117</color>
<color name="MediumSeaGreen">#306754</color>
<color name="MediumForestGreen">#347235</color>
<color name="SeaweedGreen">#437C17</color>
<color name="PineGreen">#387C44</color>
<color name="JungleGreen">#347C2C</color>
<color name="ShamrockGreen">#347C17</color>
<color name="MediumSpringGreen">#348017</color>
<color name="ForestGreen">#4E9258</color>
<color name="GreenOnion">#6AA121</color>
<color name="SpringGreen">#4AA02C</color>
<color name="LimeGreen">#41A317</color>
<color name="CloverGreen">#3EA055</color>
<color name="GreenSnake">#6CBB3C</color>
<color name="AlienGreen">#6CC417</color>
<color name="GreenApple">#4CC417</color>
<color name="YellowGreen">#52D017</color>
<color name="KellyGreen">#4CC552</color>
<color name="ZombieGreen">#54C571</color>
<color name="FrogGreen">#99C68E</color>
<color name="GreenPeas">#89C35C</color>
<color name="DollarBillGreen">#85BB65</color>
<color name="DarkSeaGreen">#8BB381</color>
<color name="IguanaGreen">#9CB071</color>
<color name="AvocadoGreen">#B2C248</color>
<color name="PistachioGreen">#9DC209</color>
<color name="SaladGreen">#A1C935</color>
<color name="HummingbirdGreen">#7FE817</color>
<color name="NebulaGreen">#59E817</color>
<color name="StoplightGoGreen">#57E964</color>
<color name="AlgaeGreen">#64E986</color>
<color name="JadeGreen">#5EFB6E</color>
<color name="Green">#00FF00</color>
<color name="EmeraldGreen">#5FFB17</color>
<color name="LawnGreen">#87F717</color>
<color name="Chartreuse">#8AFB17</color>
<color name="DragonGreen">#6AFB92</color>
<color name="Mintgreen">#98FF98</color>
<color name="GreenThumb">#B5EAAA</color>
<color name="LightJade">#C3FDB8</color>
<color name="TeaGreen">#CCFB5D</color>
<color name="GreenYellow">#B1FB17</color>
<color name="SlimeGreen">#BCE954</color>
<color name="Goldenrod">#EDDA74</color>
<color name="HarvestGold">#EDE275</color>
<color name="SunYellow">#FFE87C</color>
<color name="Yellow">#FFFF00</color>
<color name="CornYellow">#FFF380</color>
<color name="Parchment">#FFFFC2</color>
<color name="Cream">#FFFFCC</color>
<color name="LemonChiffon">#FFF8C6</color>
<color name="Cornsilk">#FFF8DC</color>
<color name="Beige">#F5F5DC</color>
<color name="AntiqueWhite">#FAEBD7</color>
<color name="BlanchedAlmond">#FFEBCD</color>
<color name="Vanilla">#F3E5AB</color>
<color name="TanBrown">#ECE5B6</color>
<color name="Peach">#FFE5B4</color>
<color name="Mustard">#FFDB58</color>
<color name="RubberDuckyYellow">#FFD801</color>
<color name="BrightGold">#FDD017</color>
<color name="Goldenbrown">#EAC117</color>
<color name="MacaroniandCheese">#F2BB66</color>
<color name="Saffron">#FBB917</color>
<color name="Beer">#FBB117</color>
<color name="Cantaloupe">#FFA62F</color>
<color name="BeeYellow">#E9AB17</color>
<color name="BrownSugar">#E2A76F</color>
<color name="BurlyWood">#DEB887</color>
<color name="DeepPeach">#FFCBA4</color>
<color name="GingerBrown">#C9BE62</color>
<color name="SchoolBusYellow">#E8A317</color>
<color name="SandyBrown">#EE9A4D</color>
<color name="FallLeafBrown">#C8B560</color>
<color name="Gold">#D4A017</color>
<color name="Sand">#C2B280</color>
<color name="CookieBrown">#C7A317</color>
<color name="Caramel">#C68E17</color>
<color name="Brass">#B5A642</color>
<color name="Khaki">#ADA96E</color>
<color name="Camelbrown">#C19A6B</color>
<color name="Bronze">#CD7F32</color>
<color name="TigerOrange">#C88141</color>
<color name="Cinnamon">#C58917</color>
<color name="DarkGoldenrod">#AF7817</color>
<color name="Copper">#B87333</color>
<color name="Wood">#966F33</color>
<color name="OakBrown">#806517</color>
<color name="Moccasin">#827839</color>
<color name="ArmyBrown">#827B60</color>
<color name="Sandstone">#786D5F</color>
<color name="Mocha">#493D26</color>
<color name="Taupe">#483C32</color>
<color name="Coffee">#6F4E37</color>
<color name="BrownBear">#835C3B</color>
<color name="RedDirt">#7F5217</color>
<color name="Sepia">#7F462C</color>
<color name="OrangeSalmon">#C47451</color>
<color name="Rust">#C36241</color>
<color name="RedFox">#C35817</color>
<color name="Chocolate">#C85A17</color>
<color name="Sedona">#CC6600</color>
<color name="PapayaOrange">#E56717</color>
<color name="HalloweenOrange">#E66C2C</color>
<color name="PumpkinOrange">#F87217</color>
<color name="ConstructionConeOrange">#F87431</color>
<color name="SunriseOrange">#E67451</color>
<color name="MangoOrange">#FF8040</color>
<color name="DarkOrange">#F88017</color>
<color name="Coral">#FF7F50</color>
<color name="BasketBallOrange">#F88158</color>
<color name="LightSalmon">#F9966B</color>
<color name="Tangerine">#E78A61</color>
<color name="DarkSalmon">#E18B6B</color>
<color name="LightCoral">#E77471</color>
<color name="BeanRed">#F75D59</color>
<color name="ValentineRed">#E55451</color>
<color name="ShockingOrange">#E55B3C</color>
<color name="Red">#FF0000</color>
<color name="Scarlet">#FF2400</color>
<color name="RubyRed">#F62217</color>
<color name="FerrariRed">#F70D1A</color>
<color name="FireEngineRed">#F62817</color>
<color name="LavaRed">#E42217</color>
<color name="LoveRed">#E41B17</color>
<color name="Grapefruit">#DC381F</color>
<color name="ChestnutRed">#C34A2C</color>
<color name="CherryRed">#C24641</color>
<color name="Mahogany">#C04000</color>
<color name="ChilliPepper">#C11B17</color>
<color name="Cranberry">#9F000F</color>
<color name="RedWine">#990012</color>
<color name="Burgundy">#8C001A</color>
<color name="BloodRed">#7E3517</color>
<color name="Sienna">#8A4117</color>
<color name="Sangria">#7E3817</color>
<color name="Firebrick">#800517</color>
<color name="Maroon">#810541</color>
<color name="PlumPie">#7D0541</color>
<color name="VelvetMaroon">#7E354D</color>
<color name="PlumVelvet">#7D0552</color>
<color name="RosyFinch">#7F4E52</color>
<color name="Puce">#7F5A58</color>
<color name="DullPurple">#7F525D</color>
<color name="RosyBrown">#B38481</color>
<color name="KhakiRose">#C5908E</color>
<color name="PinkBow">#C48189</color>
<color name="LipstickPink">#C48793</color>
<color name="Rose">#E8ADAA</color>
<color name="DesertSand">#EDC9AF</color>
<color name="PigPink">#FDD7E4</color>
<color name="CottonCandy">#FCDFFF</color>
<color name="PinkBubblegum">#FFDFDD</color>
<color name="MistyRose">#FBBBB9</color>
<color name="Pink">#FAAFBE</color>
<color name="LightPink">#FAAFBA</color>
<color name="FlamingoPink">#F9A7B0</color>
<color name="PinkRose">#E7A1B0</color>
<color name="PinkDaisy">#E799A3</color>
<color name="CadillacPink">#E38AAE</color>
<color name="CarnationPink">#F778A1</color>
<color name="BlushRed">#E56E94</color>
<color name="HotPink">#F660AB</color>
<color name="WatermelonPink">#FC6C85</color>
<color name="VioletRed">#F6358A</color>
<color name="DeepPink">#F52887</color>
<color name="PinkCupcake">#E45E9D</color>
<color name="PinkLemonade">#E4287C</color>
<color name="NeonPink">#F535AA</color>
<color name="Magenta">#FF00FF</color>
<color name="DimorphothecaMagenta">#E3319D</color>
<color name="BrightNeonPink">#F433FF</color>
<color name="PaleVioletRed">#D16587</color>
<color name="TulipPink">#C25A7C</color>
<color name="MediumVioletRed">#CA226B</color>
<color name="RoguePink">#C12869</color>
<color name="BurntPink">#C12267</color>
<color name="BashfulPink">#C25283</color>
<color name="Carnation_Pink">#C12283</color>
<color name="Plum">#B93B8F</color>
<color name="ViolaPurple">#7E587E</color>
<color name="PurpleIris">#571B7E</color>
<color name="PlumPurple">#583759</color>
<color name="Indigo">#4B0082</color>
<color name="PurpleMonster">#461B7E</color>
<color name="PurpleHaze">#4E387E</color>
<color name="Eggplant">#614051</color>
<color name="Grape">#5E5A80</color>
<color name="PurpleJam">#6A287E</color>
<color name="DarkOrchid">#7D1B7E</color>
<color name="PurpleFlower">#A74AC7</color>
<color name="MediumOrchid">#B048B5</color>
<color name="PurpleAmethyst">#6C2DC7</color>
<color name="DarkViolet">#842DCE</color>
<color name="Violet">#8D38C9</color>
<color name="PurpleSageBush">#7A5DC7</color>
<color name="LovelyPurple">#7F38EC</color>
<color name="Purple">#8E35EF</color>
<color name="AztechPurple">#893BFF</color>
<color name="MediumPurple">#8467D7</color>
<color name="JasminePurple">#A23BEC</color>
<color name="PurpleDaffodil">#B041FF</color>
<color name="TyrianPurple">#C45AEC</color>
<color name="CrocusPurple">#9172EC</color>
<color name="PurpleMimosa">#9E7BFF</color>
<color name="HeliotropePurple">#D462FF</color>
<color name="Crimson">#E238EC</color>
<color name="PurpleDragon">#C38EC7</color>
<color name="Lilac">#C8A2C8</color>
<color name="BlushPink">#E6A9EC</color>
<color name="Mauve">#E0B0FF</color>
<color name="WiseriaPurple">#C6AEC7</color>
<color name="BlossomPink">#F9B7FF</color>
<color name="Thistle">#D2B9D3</color>
<color name="Periwinkle">#E9CFEC</color>
<color name="LavenderPinocchio">#EBDDE2</color>
<color name="Lavender">#E3E4FA</color>
<color name="Pearl">#FDEEF4</color>
<color name="SeaShell">#FFF5EE</color>
<color name="MilkWhite">#FEFCFF</color>
<color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Answer (score 2):

Mostly used colors in Android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#fa3d2f</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#d9221f</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

    <!-- Android -->
    <color name="myPrimaryColor">#4688F2</color>
    <color name="myPrimaryDarkColor">#366AD3</color>
    <color name="myAccentColor">#FF9800</color>
    <color name="myDrawerBackground">#F2F2F2</color>
    <color name="myWindowBackground">#DEDEDE</color>
    <color name="myTextPrimaryColor">#000000</color>
    <color name="myNavigationColor">#000000</color>

    <color name="dim_gray">#696969</color>

    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>

    <color name="cetagory_item_bg_01">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="cetagory_item_bg_02">#d3dce5</color>
    <color name="cetagory_item_bg_03">#aecce8</color>
    <color name="cetagory_item_more_bg">#88add9</color>

    <color name="item_details_fragment_bg">#ededed</color>
    <!-- common -->
    <color name="common_white_1">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="common_white_2">#feffff</color>
    <color name="common_white_30">#4dffffff</color>
    <color name="common_white_10">#1aFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="common_gray_txt">#514e4e</color>
    <color name="common_gray_bg">#9fa0a0</color>
    <color name="common_black_10">#1a000000</color>
    <color name="common_black_30_1">#4d000000</color>
    <color name="common_black_30_2">#4d010000</color>
    <color name="common_black_50">#80000000</color>
    <color name="common_black_70">#B3000000</color>
    <color name="common_black_15">#26000000</color>
    <color name="common_red">#ed2024</color>
    <color name="common_yellow">#fff51e</color>
    <color name="common_light_gray_txt">#b9b9ba</color>
    <color name="indicator_gray">#737172</color>
    <color name="common_red_txt">#ff4141</color>
    <color name="common_blue_bg">#0055bd</color>
    <color name="fragment_bg">#efefef</color>
    <color name="main_gray_color">#9d9e9e</color>
    <color name="hint_color">#ababac</color>
    <color name="troubleshooting_txt_color">#231815</color>
    <color name="common_sc_main_color">#0055bd</color>
    <color name="common_ec_blue_txt">#0055bd</color>

    <color name="main_dark">#000000</color>
    <color name="introduction_text">#9FA0A0</color>
    <color name="orange">#FFB600</color>
    <color name="btn_login_email_pressed">#ccFFB600</color>
    <color name="text_dark">#9FA0A0</color>
    <color name="btn_login_facebook">#2E5DAC</color>
    <color name="btn_login_facebook_pressed">#802E5DAC</color>
    <color name="btn_login_twitter">#59ADEC</color>
    <color name="btn_login_twitter_pressed">#8059ADEC</color>
    <color name="spinner_background">#808080</color>
    <color name="clock_remain">#3d3939</color>
    <color name="border_bottom">#C9CACA</color>
    <color name="dash_border">#C9CACA</color>
    <color name="date_color">#b5b5b6</color>

    <!--send trouble shooting-->
    <color name="send_trouble_back_ground">#eae9e8</color>
    <color name="send_trouble_background_header">#cccccc</color>
    <color name="send_trouble_text_color_header">#666666</color>
    <color name="send_trouble_edit_text_color_boder">#c4c3c3</color>
    <color name="send_trouble_bg">#9fa0a0</color>

    <!--copy code-->
    <color name="back_ground_dialog">#90000000</color>



    <!--ec detail product-->
    <color name="ec_btn_go_to_shop_page_off">#0055bd</color>
    <color name="ec_btn_go_to_shop_page_on">#800055bd</color>
    <color name="ec_btn_go_to_detail_page_on">#80FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="ec_btn_login_facebook_off">#2675d7</color>
    <color name="ec_btn_login_facebook_on">#802675d7</color>
    <color name="ec_btn_login_twitter_on">#8044baff</color>
    <color name="ec_btn_login_twitter_off">#44baff</color>
    <color name="ec_btn_login_email_on">#80ffffff</color>
    <color name="ec_btn_login_email_off">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="ec_text_login_email">#ff5500</color>

    <color name="ec_point_manager_text_chart">#0063dd</color>
    <color name="common_green">#45cc28</color>
    <color  name="green1">#139E91</color>
    <color name="blacklight">#212121</color>
    <color name="black_opacity_60">#99000000</color>
    <color name="white_50_percent_opacity">#7fffffff</color>
    <color name="line_config">#c9caca</color>

    <color name="black_semi_transparent">#B2000000</color>
    <color name="background">#e5e5e5</color>
    <color name="half_black">#808080</color>
    <color name="white_pressed">#f1f1f1</color>
    <color name="pink">#e91e63</color>
    <color name="pink_pressed">#ec407a</color>
    <color name="blue_semi_transparent">#805677fc</color>
    <color name="blue_semi_transparent_pressed">#80738ffe</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="gray">#A9A9A9</color>
    <color name="nav_header_background">#fdfdfe</color>
    <color name="video_thumbnail_placeholder_color">#d3d3d3</color>
    <color name="video_des_background_color">#cec8c8</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

ADVANCES **COLOR.xml** file with Alphabet Order

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<!-- Android style -->
<color name="android_green">#A4C639</color>

<!-- Android Holo style -->
<color name="holo_blue_bright">#ff00ddff</color>
<color name="holo_blue_dark">#ff0099cc</color>
<color name="holo_blue_light">#ff33b5e5</color>
<color name="holo_green_dark">#ff669900</color>
<color name="holo_green_light">#ff99cc00</color>
<color name="holo_orange_dark">#ffff8800</color>
<color name="holo_orange_light">#ffffbb33</color>
<color name="holo_purple">#ffaa66cc</color>
<color name="holo_red_dark">#ffcc0000</color>
<color name="holo_red_light">#ffff4444</color>

<!-- Windows 8 style -->
<color name="win8_magenta">#FF0097</color>
<color name="win8_purple">#A200FF</color>
<color name="win8_teal">#00ABA9</color>
<color name="win8_lime">#8CBF26</color>
<color name="win8_brown">#A05000</color>
<color name="win8_pink">#E671B8</color>
<color name="win8_orange">#F09609</color>
<color name="win8_blue">#1BA1E2</color>
<color name="win8_red">#E51400</color>
<color name="win8_green">#339933</color>

<!-- Common -->
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="black">#000000</color>
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
<color name="green">#008000</color>
<color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
<color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
<color name="teal">#008080</color>
<color name="Orange">#FFA500</color>
<!-- Generic -->
<!-- Generic Dark -->
<color name="DarkTurquoise">#00CED1</color>
<color name="DarkCyan">#008B8B</color>
<color name="DarkGreen">#006400</color>
<color name="DarkSalmon">#E9967A</color>
<color name="DarkBlue">#00008B</color>
<color name="DarkOrange">#FF8C00</color>
<color name="DarkOrchid">#9932CC</color>
<color name="DarkViolet">#9400D3</color>
<color name="DarkMagenta">#8B008B</color>
<color name="DarkRed">#8B0000</color>
<color name="DarkOliveGreen">#556B2F</color>
<color name="DarkSlateGray">#2F4F4F</color>
<color name="DarkSlateBlue">#483D8B</color>
<color name="DarkSeaGreen">#8FBC8F</color>
<color name="DarkGray">#A9A9A9</color>
<color name="DarkGoldenrod">#B8860B</color>
<color name="DarkKhaki">#BDB76B</color>
<!-- Generic Light -->
<color name="LightGrey">#D3D3D3</color>
<color name="LightSteelBlue">#B0C4DE</color>
<color name="LightBlue">#ADD8E6</color>
<color name="LightPink">#FFB6C1</color>
<color name="LightSalmon">#FFA07A</color>
<color name="LightCyan">#E0FFFF</color>
<color name="LightCoral">#F08080</color>
<color name="LightSkyBlue">#87CEFA</color>
<color name="LightSeaGreen">#20B2AA</color>
<color name="LightSlateGray">#778899</color>
<color name="LightGreen">#90EE90</color>
<color name="LightYellow">#FFFFE0</color>
<color name="LightGoldenrodYellow">#FAFAD2</color>
<!-- Generic Medium -->
<color name="MediumSlateBlue">#7B68EE</color>
<color name="MediumAquamarine">#66CDAA</color>
<color name="MediumVioletRed">#C71585</color>
<color name="MediumOrchid">#BA55D3</color>
<color name="MediumPurple">#9370DB</color>
<color name="MediumBlue">#0000CD</color>
<color name="MediumTurquoise">#48D1CC</color>
<color name="MediumSeaGreen">#3CB371</color>
<color name="MediumSpringGreen">#00FA9A</color>

<!-- a -->
<color name="Azure">#F0FFFF</color>
<color name="AliceBlue">#F0F8FF</color>
<color name="AntiqueWhite">#FAEBD7</color>
<color name="Aquamarine">#7FFFD4</color>
<!-- b -->
<color name="Beige">#F5F5DC</color>
<color name="BurlyWood">#DEB887</color>
<color name="Brown">#A52A2A</color>
<color name="BlueViolet">#8A2BE2</color>
<color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
<color name="Bisque">#FFE4C4</color>
<color name="BlanchedAlmond">#FFEBCD</color>
<!-- c -->
<color name="Cornsilk">#FFF8DC</color>
<color name="Coral">#FF7F50</color>
<color name="Chocolate">#D2691E</color>
<color name="Crimson">#DC143C</color>
<color name="CornflowerBlue">#6495ED</color>
<color name="CadetBlue">#5F9EA0</color>
<color name="Chartreuse">#7FFF00</color>
<!-- d -->
<color name="DeepPink">#FF1493</color>
<color name="DeepSkyBlue">#00BFFF</color>
<color name="DimGray">#696969</color>
<color name="DodgerBlue">#1E90FF</color>
<!-- e -->
<!-- f -->
<color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
<color name="ForestGreen">#228B22</color>
<color name="FloralWhite">#FFFAF0</color>
<color name="FireBrick">#B22222</color>
<color name="Fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
<!-- g -->
<color name="Gold">#FFD700</color>
<color name="GreenYellow">#ADFF2F</color>
<color name="gray">#808080</color>
<color name="Goldenrod">#DAA520</color>
<color name="Gainsboro">#DCDCDC</color>
<color name="GhostWhite">#F8F8FF</color>
<!-- h -->
<color name="Honeydew">#F0FFF0</color>
<color name="HotPink">#FF69B4</color>
<!-- i -->
<color name="Indigo">#4B0082</color>
<color name="Ivory">#FFFFF0</color>
<color name="IndianRed">#CD5C5C</color>
<!-- j -->
<!-- k -->
<color name="Khaki">#F0E68C</color>
<!-- l -->
<color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
<color name="LawnGreen">#7CFC00</color>
<color name="LavenderBlush">#FFF0F5</color>
<color name="Linen">#FAF0E6</color>
<color name="LemonChiffon">#FFFACD</color>
<color name="Lavender">#E6E6FA</color>
<color name="LimeGreen">#32CD32</color>
<!-- m -->
<color name="maroon">#800000</color>
<color name="Moccasin">#FFE4B5</color>
<color name="Maroon">#800000</color>
<color name="MintCream">#F5FFFA</color>
<color name="Magenta">#FF00FF</color>
<color name="MidnightBlue">#191970</color>
<color name="MistyRose">#FFE4E1</color>
<!-- n -->
<color name="navy">#000080</color>
<color name="NavajoWhite">#FFDEAD</color>
<!-- o -->
<color name="olive">#808000</color>
<color name="OliveDrab">#6B8E23</color>
<color name="OrangeRed">#FF4500</color>
<color name="OldLace">#FDF5E6</color>
<color name="Orchid">#DA70D6</color>

<!-- p -->
<color name="PeachPuff">#FFDAB9</color>
<color name="Pink">#FFC0CB</color>
<color name="Peru">#CD853F</color>
<color name="PaleGoldenrod">#EEE8AA</color>
<color name="PaleVioletRed">#DB7093</color>
<color name="Plum">#DDA0DD</color>
<color name="PaleGreen">#98FB98</color>
<color name="PowderBlue">#B0E0E6</color>
<color name="PaleTurquoise">#AFEEEE</color>
<color name="PapayaWhip">#FFEFD5</color>
<!-- q -->
<!-- r -->
<color name="RoyalBlue">#4169E1</color>
<color name="RosyBrown">#BC8F8F</color>
<!-- s -->
<color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
<color name="Seashell">#FFF5EE</color>
<color name="Snow">#FFFAFA</color>
<color name="Sienna">#A0522D</color>
<color name="SpringGreen">#00FF7F</color>
<color name="SkyBlue">#87CEEB</color>
<color name="SeaGreen">#2E8B57</color>
<color name="SteelBlue">#4682B4</color>
<color name="SlateGray">#708090</color>
<color name="SlateBlue">#6A5ACD</color>
<color name="SaddleBrown">#8B4513</color>
<color name="Salmon">#FA8072</color>
<color name="SandyBrown">#F4A460</color>

<!-- t -->
<color name="Thistle">#D8BFD8</color>
<color name="Turquoise">#40E0D0</color>
<color name="Tan">#D2B48C</color>
<color name="Tomato">#FF6347</color>
<!-- u -->
<!-- v -->
<color name="purple">#800080</color>
<color name="Violet">#EE82EE</color>
<!-- w -->
<color name="WhiteSmoke">#F5F5F5</color>
<color name="Wheat">#F5DEB3</color>
<!-- x -->
<!-- y -->

<color name="YellowGreen">#9ACD32</color>
<!-- z -->

</resources>
```

Comment: now it annoys with `color/teal_200` . There is some line to add in `app/build.gradle` dependencies. The only line...

Answer (score 1):

Material Design color palettes as Android resouce is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--Material2014-->
    <!--Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769762/web-colors-in-an-android-color-xml-resource-file-->
    <!--Reference: https://m2.material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#tools-for-picking-colors-->
        <color name="Red50">#FFEBEE</color>
        <color name="Red100">#FFCDD2</color>
        <color name="Red200">#EF9A9A</color>
        <color name="Red300">#E57373</color>
        <color name="Red400">#EF5350</color>
        <color name="Red500">#F44336</color>
        <color name="Red600">#E53935</color>
        <color name="Red700">#D32F2F</color>
        <color name="Red800">#C62828</color>
        <color name="Red900">#B71C1C</color>
        <color name="RedA100">#FF8A80</color>
        <color name="RedA200">#FF5252</color>
        <color name="RedA400">#FF1744</color>
        <color name="RedA700">#D50000</color>
        <color name="Pink50">#FCE4EC</color>
        <color name="Pink100">#F8BBD0</color>
        <color name="Pink200">#F48FB1</color>
        <color name="Pink300">#F06292</color>
        <color name="Pink400">#EC407A</color>
        <color name="Pink500">#E91E63</color>
        <color name="Pink600">#D81B60</color>
        <color name="Pink700">#C2185B</color>
        <color name="Pink800">#AD1457</color>
        <color name="Pink900">#880E4F</color>
        <color name="PinkA100">#FF80AB</color>
        <color name="PinkA200">#FF4081</color>
        <color name="PinkA400">#F50057</color>
        <color name="PinkA700">#C51162</color>
        <color name="Purple50">#F3E5F5</color>
        <color name="Purple100">#E1BEE7</color>
        <color name="Purple200">#CE93D8</color>
        <color name="Purple300">#BA68C8</color>
        <color name="Purple400">#AB47BC</color>
        <color name="Purple500">#9C27B0</color>
        <color name="Purple600">#8E24AA</color>
        <color name="Purple700">#7B1FA2</color>
        <color name="Purple800">#6A1B9A</color>
        <color name="Purple900">#4A148C</color>
        <color name="PurpleA100">#EA80FC</color>
        <color name="PurpleA200">#E040FB</color>
        <color name="PurpleA400">#D500F9</color>
        <color name="PurpleA700">#AA00FF</color>
        <color name="DeepPurple50">#EDE7F6</color>
        <color name="DeepPurple100">#D1C4E9</color>
        <color name="DeepPurple200">#B39DDB</color>
        <color name="DeepPurple300">#9575CD</color>
        <color name="DeepPurple400">#7E57C2</color>
        <color name="DeepPurple500">#673AB7</color>
        <color name="DeepPurple600">#5E35B1</color>
        <color name="DeepPurple700">#512DA8</color>
        <color name="DeepPurple800">#4527A0</color>
        <color name="DeepPurple900">#311B92</color>
        <color name="DeepPurpleA100">#B388FF</color>
        <color name="DeepPurpleA200">#7C4DFF</color>
        <color name="DeepPurpleA400">#651FFF</color>
        <color name="DeepPurpleA700">#6200EA</color>
        <color name="Indigo50">#E8EAF6</color>
        <color name="Indigo100">#C5CAE9</color>
        <color name="Indigo200">#9FA8DA</color>
        <color name="Indigo300">#7986CB</color>
        <color name="Indigo400">#5C6BC0</color>
        <color name="Indigo500">#3F51B5</color>
        <color name="Indigo600">#3949AB</color>
        <color name="Indigo700">#303F9F</color>
        <color name="Indigo800">#283593</color>
        <color name="Indigo900">#1A237E</color>
        <color name="IndigoA100">#8C9EFF</color>
        <color name="IndigoA200">#536DFE</color>
        <color name="IndigoA400">#3D5AFE</color>
        <color name="IndigoA700">#304FFE</color>
        <color name="Blue50">#E3F2FD</color>
        <color name="Blue100">#BBDEFB</color>
        <color name="Blue200">#90CAF9</color>
        <color name="Blue300">#64B5F6</color>
        <color name="Blue400">#42A5F5</color>
        <color name="Blue500">#2196F3</color>
        <color name="Blue600">#1E88E5</color>
        <color name="Blue700">#1976D2</color>
        <color name="Blue800">#1565C0</color>
        <color name="Blue900">#0D47A1</color>
        <color name="BlueA100">#82B1FF</color>
        <color name="BlueA200">#448AFF</color>
        <color name="BlueA400">#2979FF</color>
        <color name="BlueA700">#2962FF</color>
        <color name="LightBlue50">#E1F5FE</color>
        <color name="LightBlue100">#B3E5FC</color>
        <color name="LightBlue200">#81D4FA</color>
        <color name="LightBlue300">#4FC3F7</color>
        <color name="LightBlue400">#29B6F6</color>
        <color name="LightBlue500">#03A9F4</color>
        <color name="LightBlue600">#039BE5</color>
        <color name="LightBlue700">#0288D1</color>
        <color name="LightBlue800">#0277BD</color>
        <color name="LightBlue900">#01579B</color>
        <color name="LightBlueA100">#80D8FF</color>
        <color name="LightBlueA200">#40C4FF</color>
        <color name="LightBlueA400">#00B0FF</color>
        <color name="LightBlueA700">#0091EA</color>
        <color name="Cyan50">#E0F7FA</color>
        <color name="Cyan100">#B2EBF2</color>
        <color name="Cyan200">#80DEEA</color>
        <color name="Cyan300">#4DD0E1</color>
        <color name="Cyan400">#26C6DA</color>
        <color name="Cyan500">#00BCD4</color>
        <color name="Cyan600">#00ACC1</color>
        <color name="Cyan700">#0097A7</color>
        <color name="Cyan800">#00838F</color>
        <color name="Cyan900">#006064</color>
        <color name="CyanA100">#84FFFF</color>
        <color name="CyanA200">#18FFFF</color>
        <color name="CyanA400">#00E5FF</color>
        <color name="CyanA700">#00B8D4</color>
        <color name="Teal50">#E0F2F1</color>
        <color name="Teal100">#B2DFDB</color>
        <color name="Teal200">#80CBC4</color>
        <color name="Teal300">#4DB6AC</color>
        <color name="Teal400">#26A69A</color>
        <color name="Teal500">#009688</color>
        <color name="Teal600">#00897B</color>
        <color name="Teal700">#00796B</color>
        <color name="Teal800">#00695C</color>
        <color name="Teal900">#004D40</color>
        <color name="TealA100">#A7FFEB</color>
        <color name="TealA200">#64FFDA</color>
        <color name="TealA400">#1DE9B6</color>
        <color name="TealA700">#00BFA5</color>
        <color name="Green50">#E8F5E9</color>
        <color name="Green100">#C8E6C9</color>
        <color name="Green200">#A5D6A7</color>
        <color name="Green300">#81C784</color>
        <color name="Green400">#66BB6A</color>
        <color name="Green500">#4CAF50</color>
        <color name="Green600">#43A047</color>
        <color name="Green700">#388E3C</color>
        <color name="Green800">#2E7D32</color>
        <color name="Green900">#1B5E20</color>
        <color name="GreenA100">#B9F6CA</color>
        <color name="GreenA200">#69F0AE</color>
        <color name="GreenA400">#00E676</color>
        <color name="GreenA700">#00C853</color>
        <color name="LightGreen50">#F1F8E9</color>
        <color name="LightGreen100">#DCEDC8</color>
        <color name="LightGreen200">#C5E1A5</color>
        <color name="LightGreen300">#AED581</color>
        <color name="LightGreen400">#9CCC65</color>
        <color name="LightGreen500">#8BC34A</color>
        <color name="LightGreen600">#7CB342</color>
        <color name="LightGreen700">#689F38</color>
        <color name="LightGreen800">#558B2F</color>
        <color name="LightGreen900">#33691E</color>
        <color name="LightGreenA100">#CCFF90</color>
        <color name="LightGreenA200">#B2FF59</color>
        <color name="LightGreenA400">#76FF03</color>
        <color name="LightGreenA700">#64DD17</color>
        <color name="Lime50">#F9FBE7</color>
        <color name="Lime100">#F0F4C3</color>
        <color name="Lime200">#E6EE9C</color>
        <color name="Lime300">#DCE775</color>
        <color name="Lime400">#D4E157</color>
        <color name="Lime500">#CDDC39</color>
        <color name="Lime600">#C0CA33</color>
        <color name="Lime700">#AFB42B</color>
        <color name="Lime800">#9E9D24</color>
        <color name="Lime900">#827717</color>
        <color name="LimeA100">#F4FF81</color>
        <color name="LimeA200">#EEFF41</color>
        <color name="LimeA400">#C6FF00</color>
        <color name="LimeA700">#AEEA00</color>
        <color name="Yellow50">#FFFDE7</color>
        <color name="Yellow100">#FFF9C4</color>
        <color name="Yellow200">#FFF59D</color>
        <color name="Yellow300">#FFF176</color>
        <color name="Yellow400">#FFEE58</color>
        <color name="Yellow500">#FFEB3B</color>
        <color name="Yellow600">#FDD835</color>
        <color name="Yellow700">#FBC02D</color>
        <color name="Yellow800">#F9A825</color>
        <color name="Yellow900">#F57F17</color>
        <color name="YellowA100">#FFFF8D</color>
        <color name="YellowA200">#FFFF00</color>
        <color name="YellowA400">#FFEA00</color>
        <color name="YellowA700">#FFD600</color>
        <color name="Amber50">#FFF8E1</color>
        <color name="Amber100">#FFECB3</color>
        <color name="Amber200">#FFE082</color>
        <color name="Amber300">#FFD54F</color>
        <color name="Amber400">#FFCA28</color>
        <color name="Amber500">#FFC107</color>
        <color name="Amber600">#FFB300</color>
        <color name="Amber700">#FFA000</color>
        <color name="Amber800">#FF8F00</color>
        <color name="Amber900">#FF6F00</color>
        <color name="AmberA100">#FFE57F</color>
        <color name="AmberA200">#FFD740</color>
        <color name="AmberA400">#FFC400</color>
        <color name="AmberA700">#FFAB00</color>
        <color name="Orange50">#FFF3E0</color>
        <color name="Orange100">#FFE0B2</color>
        <color name="Orange200">#FFCC80</color>
        <color name="Orange300">#FFB74D</color>
        <color name="Orange400">#FFA726</color>
        <color name="Orange500">#FF9800</color>
        <color name="Orange600">#FB8C00</color>
        <color name="Orange700">#F57C00</color>
        <color name="Orange800">#EF6C00</color>
        <color name="Orange900">#E65100</color>
        <color name="OrangeA100">#FFD180</color>
        <color name="OrangeA200">#FFAB40</color>
        <color name="OrangeA400">#FF9100</color>
        <color name="OrangeA700">#FF6D00</color>
        <color name="DeepOrange50">#FBE9E7</color>
        <color name="DeepOrange100">#FFCCBC</color>
        <color name="DeepOrange200">#FFAB91</color>
        <color name="DeepOrange300">#FF8A65</color>
        <color name="DeepOrange400">#FF7043</color>
        <color name="DeepOrange500">#FF5722</color>
        <color name="DeepOrange600">#F4511E</color>
        <color name="DeepOrange700">#E64A19</color>
        <color name="DeepOrange800">#D84315</color>
        <color name="DeepOrange900">#BF360C</color>
        <color name="DeepOrangeA100">#FF9E80</color>
        <color name="DeepOrangeA200">#FF6E40</color>
        <color name="DeepOrangeA400">#FF3D00</color>
        <color name="DeepOrangeA700">#DD2C00</color>
        <color name="Brown50">#EFEBE9</color>
        <color name="Brown100">#D7CCC8</color>
        <color name="Brown200">#BCAAA4</color>
        <color name="Brown300">#A1887F</color>
        <color name="Brown400">#8D6E63</color>
        <color name="Brown500">#795548</color>
        <color name="Brown600">#6D4C41</color>
        <color name="Brown700">#5D4037</color>
        <color name="Brown800">#4E342E</color>
        <color name="Brown900">#3E2723</color>
        <color name="Gray50">#FAFAFA</color>
        <color name="Gray100">#F5F5F5</color>
        <color name="Gray200">#EEEEEE</color>
        <color name="Gray300">#E0E0E0</color>
        <color name="Gray400">#BDBDBD</color>
        <color name="Gray500">#9E9E9E</color>
        <color name="Gray600">#757575</color>
        <color name="Gray700">#616161</color>
        <color name="Gray800">#424242</color>
        <color name="Gray900">#212121</color>
        <color name="BlueGray50">#ECEFF1</color>
        <color name="BlueGray100">#CFD8DC</color>
        <color name="BlueGray200">#B0BEC5</color>
        <color name="BlueGray300">#90A4AE</color>
        <color name="BlueGray400">#78909C</color>
        <color name="BlueGray500">#607D8B</color>
        <color name="BlueGray600">#546E7A</color>
        <color name="BlueGray700">#455A64</color>
        <color name="BlueGray800">#37474F</color>
        <color name="BlueGray900">#263238</color>
        <color name="Black">#000000</color>
        <color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```