# Setting The Background Color of A ListView Through XML

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am aware that I can set the background color of a ListView dynamically through some variation of the following code:

```
ListView mainListView;  
mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.listView1 );
mainListView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

However, I would like to do the identical thing through XML instead. I tried the following code without any luck (it makes no changes):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        **android:background="#FFFFFF"**
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Does anyone know of a simple way to change the background color of a ListView via XML?

Comment: I think you are inflating a costum row layout for your `listView` ? Then may b setting background of your `listitem`, will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way:

> You have to create the Color.xml file in the res/value folder of your
>   project. The code of Color.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="orange">#ff5500</color>
 <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
 <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
 <color name="date_color">#999999</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
 <color name="gray">#999999</color>
 <color name="blue">#0066cc</color>
 <color name="gold">#e6b121</color>
 <color name="blueback">#99FFFF</color>
 <color name="articlecolor">#3399FF</color> 
 <color name="article_title">#3399FF</color> 
 <color name="cachecolor">#8ad0e8</color>
</resources>
```

[Web colors in an Android color xml resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769762/android-color-xml-resource-file)

Or, try this:

```
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
```

with these colors:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html

Answer (score 1):

"#ffffff" should work. But you could also use 
:
android:background="@android:color/black"

Answer (score 0):

Since a list item has several states (pressed, focussed, selected, etc), its best to use a selector xml than a single color. See [dev doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) and this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color) for reference.
Once you create the selector, set this as the android:background.