# Text view with different colored texts in xml code

Tags: android, text, colors, textview

I need my `textview` to have different colored texts. Also I need to do this from `xml` code, non from java code. Is there anyone who knows some way for doing this? 
Thanks

e.g. I have sentence "This is red". I need words  to be green, and word **red** to be red.

Answer (score 16):

There are three ways to change the color of some text inside a textview.

1. through `strings.xml` file in (res>values), using the tag (`<![CDATA[<p>This is green <font color='hexvalue of red'>and this is red</font>.</p> ]]>`) and then declaring the textview in java code as `myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.myText));`
2. through java code, using the HTML tag  `String text = "<font color='hexvalue of green'>This is green</font> <font color='hexvalue of red'>and this is red</font>.";  myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml((text));`
3. through `Spannable` text using java code.

   `Spannable span` = `new SpannableString("My String");`

   `span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start_position,` `end_position,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);`

   `myTextView.setText(span);`

If there are other ways to do it then I'm not aware of them.
Hope this helps

Comment: #1 and #2 does not work in Kotlin, Android Studio 3.1.3

Comment: @user3561494 I've used the #1 with kotlin and for me it works:  tv_info_fimra.setText(Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.info_firma)))

Answer (score 15):

Refer your text to string.xml  and using html font tag , by using that way you can change each letter color also .

just add this in java for that string:

```
  TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

  tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.any_text)));
```

and

In string.xml:

```
 <string name="any_text">
 <![CDATA[ <b><font color=#ff0000>write</b> your <b><font color=#0000ff>text</b> here .

]]> 
  </string>
```

hope help you

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to give text color in strings.xml then check out the below code:**

```
<string name="by_continuing_i_confirm_that_i_have_nread_the_privacy_policy">
<font fgcolor='#ffffff' >By continuing, I confirm that I have \nread the</font> <font fgcolor='#2DBBDD' >Privacy Policy</font>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java class define TextView like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>write any thing here</font> "+
              "<font color=#ffcc00>write any thing here 2</font>";
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Answer (score -5):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/yourUniqueTextViewID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:textColor="@color/RED" />
```

Where "RED" is a named constant you have to define under res/values/ in an xml file. Typically i create "colors.xml".

Or see this for a good set of predefined colors: [Web colors in an Android color xml resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769762/android-color-xml-resource-file)

Comment: Thanks for reply dear friend ,but I meant this. e.g. I have sentence "This is red". I need words <This is> to be green, and word <red> to be red.