# Change color inside strings.xml

Tags: android

I am new to android, and would like to know how do I change the color of font inside the strings.xml file in a string tag.

for example I have:

```
  <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
```

I just want it to display as red and blue

thanx

Comment: This might help someone although its not recomended[androidqq6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17559656/5106406)

Comment: are you trying to change the color shown by the editor (ide) or the resulting color that will be in the app?

Answer (score 102):

Try this

For red color,

```
<string name="hello_worldRed"><![CDATA[<b><font color=#FF0000>Hello world!</font></b>]]></string>
```

For blue,

```
<string name="hello_worldBlue"><![CDATA[<b><font color=#0000FF>Hello world!</font></b>]]></string>
```

In java code,

```
//red color text
TextView redColorTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.redText);
String redString = getResources().getString(R.string.hello_worldRed)
redColorTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(redString));

//Blue color text
TextView blueColorTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blueText);
String blueString = getResources().getString(R.string.hello_worldBlue)
blueColorTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(blueString));
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the `<font>` tag with `</font>`.

Comment: From Android 7.0 on, the single-parameter `fromHtml`is deprecated. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905107/917764) or [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT) for more info.

Comment: What if we want to change the color of part of the string instead of complete string?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher Just wrap the desired part in `<font>` tags

Comment: Why can't we set color id in the `font color="@color/customBlue"`?

Answer (score 55):

For those who want to put color in String.xml directly and don't want to use color...

example

```
<string name="status_stop"><font fgcolor='#FF8E8E93'>Stopped</font></string> <!--gray-->
<string name="status_running"><font fgcolor='#FF4CD964'>Running</font></string> <!--green-->
<string name="status_error"><font fgcolor='#FFFF3B30'>Error</font></string> <!--red-->
```

as you see there is gray, red, and green, there is 8 characters, first two for transparency and other for color.

Example

```
This a description of color and transparency
#   FF               FF3B30    
    Opacity          Color
```

> ***Note:*** Put color in text in the same string.xml will not work in Android 6.0 and above

Table of opacity

```
100% — FF
99% — FC
98% — FA
97% — F7
96% — F5
95% — F2
94% — F0
93% — ED
92% — EB
91% — E8
90% — E6
89% — E3
88% — E0
87% — DE
86% — DB
85% — D9
84% — D6
83% — D4
82% — D1
81% — CF
80% — CC
79% — C9
78% — C7
77% — C4
76% — C2
75% — BF
74% — BD
73% — BA
72% — B8
71% — B5
70% — B3
69% — B0
68% — AD
67% — AB
66% — A8
65% — A6
64% — A3
63% — A1
62% — 9E
61% — 9C
60% — 99
59% — 96
58% — 94
57% — 91
56% — 8F
55% — 8C
54% — 8A
53% — 87
52% — 85
51% — 82
50% — 80
49% — 7D
48% — 7A
47% — 78
46% — 75
45% — 73
44% — 70
43% — 6E
42% — 6B
41% — 69
40% — 66
39% — 63
38% — 61
37% — 5E
36% — 5C
35% — 59
34% — 57
33% — 54
32% — 52
31% — 4F
30% — 4D
29% — 4A
28% — 47
27% — 45
26% — 42
25% — 40
24% — 3D
23% — 3B
22% — 38
21% — 36
20% — 33
19% — 30
18% — 2E
17% — 2B
16% — 29
15% — 26
14% — 24
13% — 21
12% — 1F
11% — 1C
10% — 1A
9% — 17
8% — 14
7% — 12
6% — 0F
5% — 0D
4% — 0A
3% — 08
2% — 05
1% — 03
0% — 00
```

Reference: [Understanding colors in Android (6 characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445085/understanding-colors-in-android-6-characters/11019879#11019879)

---

### Update: 10/OCT/2016

**This function is compatible with all version of android, I didn't test in android 7.0. Use this function to get color and set in textview**

Example format xml in file string and colors

```
<!-- /res/values/strings.xml -->
<string name="status_stop">Stopped</string>
<string name="status_running">Running</string>
<string name="status_error">Error</string>

<!-- /res/values/colors.xml -->
<color name="status_stop">#8E8E93</color>
<color name="status_running">#4CD964</color>
<color name="status_error">#FF3B30</color>
```

Function to get color from xml with validation for android 6.0 and above

```
public static int getColorWrapper(Context context, int id) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {//if actual version is >= 6.0
            return context.getColor(id);
        } else {
            //noinspection deprecation
            return context.getResources().getColor(id);
        }
    }
```

Example:

```
TextView status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvstatus);
status.setTextColor(getColorWrapper(myactivity.this,R.color.status_stop));
```

Reference: [getColor(int id) deprecated on Android 6.0 Marshmallow (API 23)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590714/getcolorint-id-deprecated-on-android-6-0-marshmallow-api-23)

Comment: I prefer this method as it doesn't require dynamic loading of the strings and creating an Html. You just set the string to the textview and that's it. Thanks!

Comment: Same as https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat#getcolor

Answer (score 31):

Just add your text between the font tags:

for blue color

```
<string name="hello_world"><font color='blue'>Hello world!</font></string>
```

or for red color

```
<string name="hello_world"><font color='red'>Hello world!</font></string>
```

Comment: Note that anyone using this approach should use the [Resources.getText(id:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/Resources#gettext) method to get the String and not the [Resources.getString(id:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/Resources#getstring) method. The former method retains any rich text styling in the String and the latter does not.

Comment: Also, you can use Hex colours just as well as named colours. So `<font color="#FF0000">Hello world!</font>` works just as well as `<font color="red">Hello world!</font>`.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to support text **formatting** from within your `strings.xml` file, you have to escape the tags – or use a **CDATA** section.. Otherwise Android simply ignores them when reading the resource file.

e.g

```
<string name="hello_world">
<![CDATA[
<p>This is a html-formatted string with <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i> text</p>
<p>This is another paragraph of the same string.</p>
]]>
</string>
```

**OR**

```
String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: thanx for the feedback, and if I want to change my application's label color how would I do that, in the .xml files?

Comment: <string name="hello_world"><font fgcolor="red">Hello</font> </font fgcolor="blue">world!</font></string>. But note that this only works on a relatively short list of built-in colors: aqua, black, blue, fuchsia, green, grey, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, red, silver, teal, white, and yellow

Comment: Also, I'm confused: why the CDATA? This would *escape* the formatting tags so they don't do anything.

Comment: @B.shruti it is printing the tag because you didnt parse it programmatically as a Html using Html.fromHtml...check Silambarasan answer

Answer (score 15):

I would use a `SpannableString` to change the color.

```
int colorBlue = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
    String text = getString(R.string.text);
    SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(text);
    // here we set the color
    spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(colorBlue), 0, text.length(), 0);
```

**OR** you may try [this](http://android.joao.jp/2012/03/string-resources-with-font-color.html)

Comment: just in case if the link goes dead,
<resources>
  <string name="some_text">this is <font fgcolor="#ffff0000">red</font></string>
</resources>

Answer (score 14):

If you wish to change the font color inside `string.xml` file, you may try the following code.

```
<resources>
   <string name="hello_world"><font fgcolor="#ffff0000">Hello world!</font></string>
</resources>
```

Comment: It used to work; it broke in 4.x. See TWiStErRob's explanation and work-around at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11577658/338479.

Answer (score 13):

```
<string name="hello_world"><font fgcolor="red">Hello</font>
    </font fgcolor="blue">world!</font></string>
```

But note that this only works on a relatively short list of built-in colors: aqua, black, blue, fuchsia, green, grey, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, red, silver, teal, white, and yellow. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31655150/338479 for a way to do it with arbitrary colors.

Answer (score 5):

This is the easy and the best way to add multiple colors in one string.

```
<string name="color_as">Any Text<font fgcolor='#FF0000'> *Text 1* </font><font fgcolor='#ffc821'> *Text 2 * </font></string>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't. `strings.xml` is just here to define the raw text messages. You should (must) use `styles.xml` to define reusable visual styles to apply to your widgets.

Think of it as a good practice to separate the concerns. You can work on the visual styles independently from the text messages.

Comment: @user2042227 also consider a `colors.xml` file so that you define all your colors defined in a single place, and only reference them in other places like `@color/app_background`

Comment: Personally, I do not use colors.xml, only styles.xml. It may be a habit from CSS files (in HTML) and XAML customtemplates (in WPF/WindowsPhone). This extra file does not separate concerns, but enables the reuse of a same color in different elements.

Answer (score 3):

For those who have come here for the answers from searching in google at 2021
Just use

```
<string name="hello_world"><font color="#your_color_in_hexa"> Hello</font> world!</string>
```

This above code will color the **"Hello"** part of the text

Answer (score 1):

You do not set such attributes in `strings.xml` type of files. You need to set it in your code. or (which is better solution) create style with colors you want and apply to your `TextView`

Answer (score 1):

Use CDATA in the below way for formatting your text

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">DemoShareActionButton</string>
<string name="intro_message">
    <b>
    <![CDATA[ This sample shows you how a provide a context-sensitive ShareActionProvider.
    ]]>
    </b>
    </string>
```

Just add any tag you want before the `<![CDATA[` and you will get your proper output.