# Android- Put some texts on ToggleButton

Tags: android, textview, android-togglebutton

I need to put 2 texts on `ToggleButton`, i.e. two different texts, so I could change just one of them.

I don't want to put another `TextView` on the `ToggleButton`, because I need that the second text will looked as part of the button, and the location of the button is changing in relation to other parts of the application

There is any built way to do that? or anyone has another idea?

Comment: Are you wanting to change the text of the ToggleButton when it is pressed or at some other time?

Comment: Yes, but I want to change only part of the text, like change the color of some words.

Comment: Here's a question that addresses that -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630160/change-color-inside-strings-xml -- take a look