# different colors for EdtiText hint and TextInputLayout label

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

How I can set different colors for EditText hint and it's TextInputLayout label. 
I tried do it in themes and styles, with android:textColorHint in EditText and TextInputLayout directly, and app:hintTextAppearance attribute on TextInputLayout.
But no one works! Always used same color.

I think, it is because TextInputLayout code:

```
this.mDefaultTextColor = this.mEditText.getHintTextColors();
```

I use 23.1.1 version of design library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Is there simple way to do this?
I only see way to write descendat of AppCompatEditText, but don't like it

Comment: have you ever consider using styles in theme?

Comment: Do you mean some concrete styles?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546430/how-to-change-the-floating-label-color-of-textinputlayout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630160/change-color-inside-strings-xml