# How do I reference a color from a string resource to format my text?

Tags: android, android-resources

My strings.xml contains the following string resource

```
<string name="contacts"><font fgcolor="#FF00FFFF">+</font> Contacts</string>
```

It is working fine  and sets the textcolor to `#FF00FFFF`

But if I try to reference a color

```
<string name="contacts"><font fgcolor="@color/strings_font_fgcolor_cyan">+</font> Contacts</string>
```

it does **not** work.

I have added the color

```
<color name="strings_font_fgcolor_cyan">#FF00FFFF</color>
```

How I can reference this color from my string resource?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19630203/5719764) might be related to your problem

Comment: there is no way to do that AFAIK. Only workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference a color resource value from within your strings. You will have to keep using `fgcolor="#FF00FFFF"` or format your text at runtime.

---

Everything between `<string name="contacts">` and `</string>` is treated as your text and it is not processed any further.

If you want to use your resource color, you will have to do this at *runtime*, by parsing / replacing parts in your String with the loaded value, or manually adding the right tags to it.