# Highlighting border of the row in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a scrollable listview. I need to highlight the top and bottom border of the row like this[image: ()] .As am a newbie tell me how to do this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selectorcolor"
```

In drawable create like this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#000000"
        android:startColor="#000000"
        android:type="linear"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#800080"
        android:dashWidth="2dp"/>    

</shape>
```

Comment: This is working but i need borders only on top and bottom of the view not on sides. can u please tell me how can i do that

Comment: Stroke can in four sides, better create a image like that set as background instead of drawable

Answer (score 1):

Create a selector file like this for different states of list view under drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@color/app_tint_pressed"
            android:state_selected="true"/>
      <item android:drawable="@color/app_tint_pressed"
             android:state_pressed="true" />

      <item android:drawable="@color/app_tint" />
</selector>
```

Apply this file like this under ListView in xml

```
android:listSelector = @drawable/myselector
```

For different states check state list on this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

you can use nine-patch images and color as well for different states in your case the normal state is black color and for pressed state either create a nine-patch image with black and borders you want or you can create it in xml as well

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#800080"
    android:dashWidth="2dp"/>
```

Comment: here for app_tint color i need to display color code in string file ah? it's showing error

Comment: app tint color in your case would be black as per your image so you can use #000000 or @android:color/black or you can create a color file under values folder and define the color there and refer it like i have done @color/app_tint like you do for string resources the difference is colors are defined with color tag. check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769762/android-color-xml-resource-file

Comment: if i apply this selection is made for only around the textview not for whole row, can u tell me how to achieve this for whole row

Comment: it shouldnt happen that way but you can try a different approach instead of applying the selector file at listSelector , apply the file as a background to the parent view (Linear , relative etc) you are using for the layout file you provide in the custom adapter for each row

Comment: i solved that issue it's because i assigned my layout width as wrap_content instead of fill_parent. Once i changed that my error got resolved. Thanks for ur help :-)

Comment: An upvote would be nice if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Just add following detail in the listview in xml file

android:divider="#FF3366"
  android:dividerHeight="3dp"

Answer (score 0):

Try this according to your code

```
viewHolder.imageview.setText(entry.getString("calculator"));
        if(position % 2 == 0){
            viewHolder.linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey);

        }
        else{
            //viewHolder.linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        }
```

It will change the color of row

Answer (score 0):

set the view's background to a xml file. in resource drawable we can use xml files. check the Api demos drawable folder. that xml file contains this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_image_in_normal_state" />

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_image_in_pressed_state_with_border" />

</selector>
```

and assign this xml filename in view's background.

also refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/package-summary.html)