# how to give same background color to two different TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I just want to give the same background to my both text view.

My code is :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:background="#f3f3f3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="192.00 $"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Recharge Limit"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: your question is not clear try to elaborate

Comment: Hey ,thanks for response
My question is i have two different textview i below another I just want to give them same bg color so that they look like one

Comment: Use android:background="#f3f3f3" in your 2nd textview as well?!?

Comment: just declare your color in your res/colors.xml and
now set your text background color using android:background="@colors/color_name" for both textview

Comment: this also works for background
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15619017/2855059

Comment: Show your Screen What You want actual...... According to your question already answer in comment

Comment: Set your two *Text View* in either *Relative Layout* or *Linear Layout* as `root layout` and you can provide *background* to that layout so it will hold *background* for both.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in comments your second `Text View` is below to first one. So you can put both `Text View` in `Linear Layout` view with orientation vertical and set background to `Linear Layout` so that both `Text View` will have same color.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f3f3f3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="192.00 $"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="192.00 $"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your color in `res/values color.xml`

```
 <color name="bg_tv_color">#f3f3f3</color>
```

and in your `Text View` tag add.

```
android:background="@color/bg_color"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can custom style for text view  `<style name="TexViewStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>` and use in text view `

```
<TextView
    android:text="Test 2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/TexViewStyle"/>`
```