# Is there a Pre-made color.xml file

Tags: android, xml

I have looked everywhere all morning. Is there a link somewhere to a pre-made colors.xml file I can copy and add to my resource file? I found one but it only had about 7 color listed in this fashion and it worked fine.
  `<item name="gray" type="color">#686868</item>`
I would like to find an **extensive** list for future use. Possibly grouped by color family rather than by name.

Thank you in advance for any help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web colors in an Android color xml resource file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769762/web-colors-in-an-android-color-xml-resource-file)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I finally found a couple decent ones. That figures! I'll post the links here for others in the future. However they are not grouped by color family, just alphabetically.

[960 colors arranged alphabetically](https://gist.github.com/VenomVendor/6857539)

[A somewhat shorter colors list. This one uses capitals, I'm not sure if that matters](https://github.com/wtsang02/colors/blob/master/color.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you just need all these colors you found.

Here you find all Material colors provided by Google: 
[Color Palette](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette)

Comment: I did see that, thank you. I even downloaded the file. But it isn't a format that can be copy and pasted into XML for the resources file. And you have to have Photoshop or Illustrator in order to open the file that page provided. I did find links eventually. I posted them below for others. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many is here but I'm sure it's a lot less than 960

```
<color name="red_50">#FFEBEE</color>
<color name="red_100">#FFCDD2</color>
<color name="red_200">#EF9A9A</color>
<color name="red_300">#E57373</color>
<color name="red_400">#EF5350</color>
<color name="red_500">#F44336</color>
<color name="red_600">#E53935</color>
<color name="red_700">#D32F2F</color>
<color name="red_800">#C62828</color>
<color name="red_900">#B71C1C</color>
<color name="red_A100">#FF8A80</color>
<color name="red_A200">#FF5252</color>
<color name="red_A400">#FF1744</color>
<color name="red_A700">#D50000</color>

<color name="deep_purple_50">#EDE7F6</color>
<color name="deep_purple_100">#D1C4E9</color>
<color name="deep_purple_200">#B39DDB</color>
<color name="deep_purple_300">#9575CD</color>
<color name="deep_purple_400">#7E57C2</color>
<color name="deep_purple_500">#673AB7</color>
<color name="deep_purple_600">#5E35B1</color>
<color name="deep_purple_700">#512DA8</color>
<color name="deep_purple_800">#4527A0</color>
<color name="deep_purple_900">#311B92</color>
<color name="deep_purple_A100">#B388FF</color>
<color name="deep_purple_A200">#7C4DFF</color>
<color name="deep_purple_A400">#651FFF</color>
<color name="deep_purple_A700">#6200EA</color>

<color name="light_blue_50">#E1F5FE</color>
<color name="light_blue_100">#B3E5FC</color>
<color name="light_blue_200">#81D4FA</color>
<color name="light_blue_300">#4FC3F7</color>
<color name="light_blue_400">#29B6F6</color>
<color name="light_blue_500">#03A9F4</color>
<color name="light_blue_600">#039BE5</color>
<color name="light_blue_700">#0288D1</color>
<color name="light_blue_800">#0277BD</color>
<color name="light_blue_900">#01579B</color>
<color name="light_blue_A100">#80D8FF</color>
<color name="light_blue_A200">#40C4FF</color>
<color name="light_blue_A400">#00B0FF</color>
<color name="light_blue_A700">#0091EA</color>

<color name="green_50">#E8F5E9</color>
<color name="green_100">#C8E6C9</color>
<color name="green_200">#A5D6A7</color>
<color name="green_300">#81C784</color>
<color name="green_400">#66BB6A</color>
<color name="green_500">#4CAF50</color>
<color name="green_600">#43A047</color>
<color name="green_700">#388E3C</color>
<color name="green_800">#2E7D32</color>
<color name="green_900">#1B5E20</color>
<color name="green_A100">#B9F6CA</color>
<color name="green_A200">#69F0AE</color>
<color name="green_A400">#00E676</color>
<color name="green_A700">#00C853</color>

<color name="yellow_50">#FFFDE7</color>
<color name="yellow_100">#FFF9C4</color>
<color name="yellow_200">#FFF59D</color>
<color name="yellow_300">#FFF176</color>
<color name="yellow_400">#FFEE58</color>
<color name="yellow_500">#FFEB3B</color>
<color name="yellow_600">#FDD835</color>
<color name="yellow_700">#FBC02D</color>
<color name="yellow_800">#F9A825</color>
<color name="yellow_900">#F57F17</color>
<color name="yellow_A100">#FFFF8D</color>
<color name="yellow_A200">#FFFF00</color>
<color name="yellow_A400">#FFEA00</color>
<color name="yellow_A700">#FFD600</color>

<color name="deep_orange_50">#FBE9E7</color>
<color name="deep_orange_100">#FFCCBC</color>
<color name="deep_orange_200">#FFAB91</color>
<color name="deep_orange_300">#FF8A65</color>
<color name="deep_orange_400">#FF7043</color>
<color name="deep_orange_500">#FF5722</color>
<color name="deep_orange_600">#F4511E</color>
<color name="deep_orange_700">#E64A19</color>
<color name="deep_orange_800">#D84315</color>
<color name="deep_orange_900">#BF360C</color>
<color name="deep_orange_A100">#FF9E80</color>
<color name="deep_orange_A200">#FF6E40</color>
<color name="deep_orange_A400">#FF3D00</color>
<color name="deep_orange_A700">#DD2C00</color>

<color name="blue_grey_50">#ECEFF1</color>
<color name="blue_grey_100">#CFD8DC</color>
<color name="blue_grey_200">#B0BEC5</color>
<color name="blue_grey_300">#90A4AE</color>
<color name="blue_grey_400">#78909C</color>
<color name="blue_grey_500">#607D8B</color>
<color name="blue_grey_600">#546E7A</color>
<color name="blue_grey_700">#455A64</color>
<color name="blue_grey_800">#37474F</color>
<color name="blue_grey_900">#263238</color>

<color name="pink_50">#FCE4EC</color>
<color name="pink_100">#F8BBD0</color>
<color name="pink_200">#F48FB1</color>
<color name="pink_300">#F06292</color>
<color name="pink_400">#EC407A</color>
<color name="pink_500">#E91E63</color>
<color name="pink_600">#D81B60</color>
<color name="pink_700">#C2185B</color>
<color name="pink_800">#AD1457</color>
<color name="pink_900">#880E4F</color>
<color name="pink_A100">#FF80AB</color>
<color name="pink_A200">#FF4081</color>
<color name="pink_A400">#F50057</color>
<color name="pink_A700">#C51162</color>

<color name="indigo_50">#E8EAF6</color>
<color name="indigo_100">#C5CAE9</color>
<color name="indigo_200">#9FA8DA</color>
<color name="indigo_300">#7986CB</color>
<color name="indigo_400">#5C6BC0</color>
<color name="indigo_500">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="indigo_600">#3949AB</color>
<color name="indigo_700">#303F9F</color>
<color name="indigo_800">#283593</color>
<color name="indigo_900">#1A237E</color>
<color name="indigo_A100">#8C9EFF</color>
<color name="indigo_A200">#536DFE</color>
<color name="indigo_A400">#3D5AFE</color>
<color name="indigo_A700">#304FFE</color>

<color name="cyan_50">#E0F7FA</color>
<color name="cyan_100">#B2EBF2</color>
<color name="cyan_200">#80DEEA</color>
<color name="cyan_300">#4DD0E1</color>
<color name="cyan_400">#26C6DA</color>
<color name="cyan_500">#00BCD4</color>
<color name="cyan_600">#00ACC1</color>
<color name="cyan_700">#0097A7</color>
<color name="cyan_800">#00838F</color>
<color name="cyan_900">#006064</color>
<color name="cyan_A100">#84FFFF</color>
<color name="cyan_A200">#18FFFF</color>
<color name="cyan_A400">#00E5FF</color>
<color name="cyan_A700">#00B8D4</color>

<color name="light_green_50">#F1F8E9</color>
<color name="light_green_100">#DCEDC8</color>
<color name="light_green_200">#C5E1A5</color>
<color name="light_green_300">#AED581</color>
<color name="light_green_400">#9CCC65</color>
<color name="light_green_500">#8BC34A</color>
<color name="light_green_600">#7CB342</color>
<color name="light_green_700">#689F38</color>
<color name="light_green_800">#558B2F</color>
<color name="light_green_900">#33691E</color>
<color name="light_green_A100">#CCFF90</color>
<color name="light_green_A200">#B2FF59</color>
<color name="light_green_A400">#76FF03</color>
<color name="light_green_A700">#64DD17</color>

<color name="amber_50">#FFF8E1</color>
<color name="amber_100">#FFECB3</color>
<color name="amber_200">#FFE082</color>
<color name="amber_300">#FFD54F</color>
<color name="amber_400">#FFCA28</color>
<color name="amber_500">#FFC107</color>
<color name="amber_600">#FFB300</color>
<color name="amber_700">#FFA000</color>
<color name="amber_800">#FF8F00</color>
<color name="amber_900">#FF6F00</color>
<color name="amber_A100">#FFE57F</color>
<color name="amber_A200">#FFD740</color>
<color name="amber_A400">#FFC400</color>
<color name="amber_A700">#FFAB00</color>

<color name="brown_50">#EFEBE9</color>
<color name="brown_100">#D7CCC8</color>
<color name="brown_200">#BCAAA4</color>
<color name="brown_300">#A1887F</color>
<color name="brown_400">#8D6E63</color>
<color name="brown_500">#795548</color>
<color name="brown_600">#6D4C41</color>
<color name="brown_700">#5D4037</color>
<color name="brown_800">#4E342E</color>
<color name="brown_900">#3E2723</color>

<color name="purple_50">#F3E5F5</color>
<color name="purple_100">#E1BEE7</color>
<color name="purple_200">#CE93D8</color>
<color name="purple_300">#BA68C8</color>
<color name="purple_400">#AB47BC</color>
<color name="purple_500">#9C27B0</color>
<color name="purple_600">#8E24AA</color>
<color name="purple_700">#7B1FA2</color>
<color name="purple_800">#6A1B9A</color>
<color name="purple_900">#4A148C</color>
<color name="purple_A100">#EA80FC</color>
<color name="purple_A200">#E040FB</color>
<color name="purple_A400">#D500F9</color>
<color name="purple_A700">#AA00FF</color>

<color name="blue_50">#E3F2FD</color>
<color name="blue_100">#BBDEFB</color>
<color name="blue_200">#90CAF9</color>
<color name="blue_300">#64B5F6</color>
<color name="blue_400">#42A5F5</color>
<color name="blue_500">#2196F3</color>
<color name="blue_600">#1E88E5</color>
<color name="blue_700">#1976D2</color>
<color name="blue_800">#1565C0</color>
<color name="blue_900">#0D47A1</color>
<color name="blue_A100">#82B1FF</color>
<color name="blue_A200">#448AFF</color>
<color name="blue_A400">#2979FF</color>
<color name="blue_A700">#2962FF</color>

<color name="teal_50">#E0F2F1</color>
<color name="teal_100">#B2DFDB</color>
<color name="teal_200">#80CBC4</color>
<color name="teal_300">#4DB6AC</color>
<color name="teal_400">#26A69A</color>
<color name="teal_500">#009688</color>
<color name="teal_600">#00897B</color>
<color name="teal_700">#00796B</color>
<color name="teal_800">#00695C</color>
<color name="teal_900">#004D40</color>
<color name="teal_A100">#A7FFEB</color>
<color name="teal_A200">#64FFDA</color>
<color name="teal_A400">#1DE9B6</color>
<color name="teal_A700">#00BFA5</color>

<color name="lime_50">#F9FBE7</color>
<color name="lime_100">#F0F4C3</color>
<color name="lime_200">#E6EE9C</color>
<color name="lime_300">#DCE775</color>
<color name="lime_400">#D4E157</color>
<color name="lime_500">#CDDC39</color>
<color name="lime_600">#C0CA33</color>
<color name="lime_700">#AFB42B</color>
<color name="lime_800">#9E9D24</color>
<color name="lime_900">#827717</color>
<color name="lime_A100">#F4FF81</color>
<color name="lime_A200">#EEFF41</color>
<color name="lime_A400">#C6FF00</color>
<color name="lime_A700">#AEEA00</color>

<color name="orange_50">#FFF3E0</color>
<color name="orange_100">#FFE0B2</color>
<color name="orange_200">#FFCC80</color>
<color name="orange_300">#FFB74D</color>
<color name="orange_400">#FFA726</color>
<color name="orange_500">#FF9800</color>
<color name="orange_600">#FB8C00</color>
<color name="orange_700">#F57C00</color>
<color name="orange_800">#EF6C00</color>
<color name="orange_900">#E65100</color>
<color name="orange_A100">#FFD180</color>
<color name="orange_A200">#FFAB40</color>
<color name="orange_A400">#FF9100</color>
<color name="orange_A700">#FF6D00</color>

<color name="grey_50">#FAFAFA</color>
<color name="grey_100">#F5F5F5</color>
<color name="grey_200">#EEEEEE</color>
<color name="grey_300">#E0E0E0</color>
<color name="grey_400">#BDBDBD</color>
<color name="grey_500">#9E9E9E</color>
<color name="grey_600">#757575</color>
<color name="grey_700">#616161</color>
<color name="grey_800">#424242</color>
<color name="grey_900">#212121</color>

<color name="black">#000000</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```