# Error:error: '#fffffffff' is incompatible with attribute android:color (attr) color

Tags: android, button, colors

[image]

can anyone help me solve the problem?

Comment: `#fffffffff` has 1 `f` too many (9 instead of 8).

Comment: it was run!!! Thankyou very much Micheal

Comment: 6 Fs (#FFFFFF) does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Color Hex Code should be of max 8 digit, where first 2 values represent the alpha value and last 6 digits results for the color (rgb).

i.e:-

```
#FFFFFFFF
  |---------------- Alpha
     |-----------------------Color (#RGB)
```

The value that you have used for colour contains 9Fs

Answer (score 0):

The color is incompatible with the android attribute color, try this `<solid android:color="?attr/butBackColor" />`
or `android:background="#FFFFFF"`

**EDIT**
Also, here is a link for reference for colors
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7323234/6914251

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when use custom attribute  and figure out i wrongly use

`#00fffff`

I forgot one `f`, So don't forget that hex color can have **3 digits** or **6 digits** or **8 digits**