# How to translate a colour name into rgb, rgba or hexadecimal

Tags: kotlin

Very simple question, i hope theres a simple answer. I am creating a mobile app that receives css styles from a website and translates the colour into the valid `view.setBackgroundColor()`.

So for example once i have extracted a substring from the style that sais `"background-color:red;"`, How would i convert that colour `"red"` into the correct rgb value which i believe would be `view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0))` or the correct hexadecimal value which i believe would be `view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"))` according to [the W3schools color picker](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp)?

Comment: As far as I know web colors have names,
so make a name-value map. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors

Comment: While there are only sixteen basic web colours, Wikipedia lists hundreds of extended colours — too many to fit comfortably into code (such as a `Map` initialiser or `when` statement).  I'd suggest putting the colour names and hex values into a text file, and then reading that into a `Map`.  (Don't have time to write the code now… it's left as an exercise :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave georkost's answer an upvote because its one way of doing it. However in the end i added the css colors and their translated color hashes to my colors.xml file using the xml copied from [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17544693/10334519) and then i used the following code.

```
val cssColor = context.resources.getIdentifier(namedColor.toLowerCase(
                Locale.ENGLISH), "color", context.packageName)

            if (cssColor != 0) {
                // outputting this if condition is met
                view.setTextColor( ContextCompat.getColor(context, cssColor) )
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create an enum from the values you get. You could create an enum class that will translate the values you get from site to actual hex or rgb based values

```kotlin
when(serverValue) {
  "red" -> "#FFFFFF"
  "green" -> "#FFFABA"
}
```

The snippet is just to give you an idea