# android change view's background color when state changes

Tags: android, colors, selector, drawable, statelist

how to use color state list for background?
I know `android:background="@drawable/drawable_selector"`, but `android:background="@color/color_selector"` will cause exceptions.
but `android:background="#FFFFFF"` works again, can anyone explains why?

now i want to change a layout's background color(not a drawable) when it's pressed, 
how to do it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009477/view-on-press-onpress-change-background-color-on-press-how-do-i-show-that-the

Comment: can you post color_selector.xml ?

Comment: which exception?? Post logcat

Comment: color_selector:
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="#FFBC09" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="#FEFEFE" android:state_pressed="false" />

</selector>

and the exception is like to say XML parse error."item" needs a drawable attribute.

Answer (score 0):

dynamically you can change like this. Use this if it is useful for you - 
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.string.red)));

Answer (score 0):

put the color in res/values/colors.xml,
like #FFFFFF,
and then create a drawable xml in drawable directory,
,that is ok.